# Can I change the checkbox size using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the size of a checkbox using CSS or HTML across browsers?

`width` and `size` work in IE6+, but not with Firefox, where the checkbox stays 16x16 even if I set a smaller size.

Comment: This is hard to do cross-browser. Roger Johansson has [investigated](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/) this rather extensively.

Comment: Reading all the comments - there is a really simple way to do this without involving CSS:

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" value="on" style="width:110%; height:110%" >

Comment: Use this simple ans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805394/how-to-change-size-of-icheck-checkbox-and-add-border-radius

Comment: @Williamz902 the `style=` tag is CSS...

Answer (score 535):

It's a little ugly (due to the scaling up), but it works on most newer browsers:

```css
input[type=checkbox]
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  transform: scale(2);
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Might want to wrap a span around your checkbox text */
.checkboxtext
{
  /* Checkbox text */
  font-size: 110%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input  type="checkbox" name="optiona" id="opta" checked />
<span class="checkboxtext">
  Option A
</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="optionb" id="optb" />
<span class="checkboxtext">
  Option B
</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="optionc" id="optc" />
<span class="checkboxtext">
  Option C
</span>
```

Comment: this seems to be the correct answer as the one marked as answer offers no solutions in many cases (no solution to firefox on xp? no chrome at all?), is outdated and only contains a link and a comment of not much value.

Comment: @jdw +1 for this answer and even I had the need to do this and your answer was helpful. But somehow I find that the 'scaled' checkbox appears a little distorted. I don't know if this is a thing with FF or my OS (Ubuntu 12.04). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: the scale() needs 2 parameters for chrome, FF and IE I think. So if you just change all the scales to scale(2,2) it should work every browser.

Comment: scale() is a perfect solution for android browsers

Comment: The inputs look super blurry in IE when scaled up, even with both parameters. Can't seem to find a fix for this, even with the zoom property applied.

Comment: Works great except when I try on a Retina display Macbook Pro. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Warning: IE checkboxes are incredibly pixelated. Chrome uses SVGs for the checkbox apparently and they're able to cleanly scale it indefinitely.

Comment: All browsers except Safari and Android no longer require prefixes.

Comment: add `transform: scale(2);` too, to ensure more for any browser

Comment: Unless you're *still* worried about IE8, just use `scale()` like in @Numbers response (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: idk if this is something that chrome has changed recently but using scale makes these look blurry

Comment: You might want to adjust the padding and margin and also move the other elements appropriately as scaling does not increase the actual element size.

Comment: In Safari, there is no visual difference between `scale(1.5)` and `scale(2)`... they render identically... like `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.5`, etc. are always rounded up.

Comment: scaling looks aweful, at scale 2 you already see the individual pixels. I would never choose this solution for beautiful big css checkboxes.

Answer (score 502):

Working solution for all modern browsers.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> Test</label>
```

---

[Compatibility:](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

- IE: 10+
- FF: 16+
- Chrome: 36+
- Safari: 9+
- Opera: 23+
- iOS Safari: 9.2+
- Chrome for Android: 51+

---

Appearance:

- [image: Scaled checkboxes on Chrome, Win 10]  Chrome 58 (May 2017), Windows 10

Comment: Does this cover older browsers like ie 8?

Comment: @Huangism No, the code above won't have any effect in IE 8 which doesn't support the `transform` property.  IE 9 supports `-ms-transform` which you could use, however some say it's quite pixelated so might be better to leave IE 9 with the default.

Comment: Isn't above approach bad, because there is a limit for scale as it causes checkbox to be pixelated.

Comment: Extremely pixelated on Chrome 64 with macOS 10.13.3 :( https://www.timo-ernst.net/misc/zeug/cb-pixel.jpg

Comment: Still pixelated on Chrome 76.

Comment: Doesn't look like this works at all anymore in Safari 13 on Mac OS Catalina.. can scale down below 1 but not up and above 1

Comment: What happens in my case is that things are increased in size but keeping its center position. So for example if I apply to `<html>`, the whole page goes of screen. Or if applied to an `input`, it goes over the label next to it.

Answer (score 91):

An easy solution is use the property `zoom`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    zoom: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Not sure it works in all browsers, but it looks prettier on screen than the scale transform solution.

Comment: On Chrome 64 with macOS 10.13.3 this looks way less pixelated than using transform + scale

Comment: Highly discouraged by Mozilla.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: It's kinda interesting that Mozilla is discouraging it while Firefox is almost the only browser that doesn't support it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom

Comment: not supported in firefox

Answer (score 61):

**2020 version** - using pseudo-elements, size depends on font size.

Default checkbox/radio is rendered outside of screen, but CSS creates virtual elements very similar to default elements. Supports all browsers, no blur. Size depends on font size. Keyboard actions (space, tabs) are also supported.

https://jsfiddle.net/ohf7nmzy/2/

```css
body{
    padding:0 20px;
}
.big{
    font-size: 50px;
}

/* CSS below will force radio/checkbox size be same as font size */
label{
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
/* radio */
input[type=radio]{
    width: 1em;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateX(-9999px);
}
input[type=radio] + label:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
input[type=radio] + label:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
/*checked*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b88fd;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.3);
}
/*focused*/
input[type=radio]:focus + label:before{
    border: 0.2em solid #8eb9fb;
    margin-top: -0.2em;
    margin-left: -0.2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #3b88fd;
}


/*checkbox/*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    width: 1em;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateX(-9999px);
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10%;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
/*checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b88fd;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "\2713";
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b88fd;
    border-radius: 10%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
}
/*focused*/
input[type=checkbox]:focus + label:before{
    border: 0.1em solid #8eb9fb;
    margin-top: -0.1em;
    margin-left: -0.1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #3b88fd;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="ee" checked /> 
<label for="ee">Checkbox small</label>

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_2" id="ff" /> 
<label for="ff">Checkbox small</label>

<hr />

<div class="big">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_3" id="gg" checked /> 
    <label for="gg">Checkbox big</label>

    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_4" id="hh" /> 
    <label for="hh">Checkbox big</label>
</div>


<hr />


<input type="radio" name="radio_1" id="aa" value="1" checked /> 
<label for="aa">Radio small</label>

<br />

<input type="radio" name="radio_1" id="bb" value="2" /> 
<label for="bb">Radio small</label>

<hr />

<div class="big">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_2" id="cc" value="1" checked /> 
    <label for="cc">Radio big</label>

    <br />

    <input type="radio" name="radio_2" id="dd" value="2" /> 
    <label for="dd">Radio big</label>
</div>
```

**2017 version** - using zoom or scale

Browser will use non-standard `zoom` feature if it is supported (nice quality) or standard `transform: scale` (blurry on Safari) as fallback.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksvx2txb/11/

```css
@supports (zoom:2) {
    input[type="radio"],  input[type=checkbox]{
    zoom: 2;
    }
}
@supports not (zoom:2) {
    input[type="radio"],  input[type=checkbox]{
        transform: scale(2);
        margin: 15px;
    }
}
label{
  /* fix vertical align issues */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="aa" value="1" id="aa" checked /> 
<label for="aa">Radio 1</label>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="aa" value="2" id="bb" /> 
<label for="bb">Radio 2</label>

<br /><br />

<input  type="checkbox" name="optiona" id="cc" checked /> 
<label for="cc">Checkbox 1</label>
<br />
<input  type="checkbox" name="optiona" id="dd" /> 
<label for="dd">Checkbox 1</label>
```

Comment: Zoom looks like it works fine on FQ. Maybe watch out for older versions of Gecko?

Answer (score 31):

I just came out with this:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {content:"☐";}
input:checked + label:before {content:"☑";}
label:hover {color:blue;}
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" /><label for="check">Checkbox</label>
```

Of course, thanks to this, you can change the value of `content` to your needs and use an image if you wish or use another font...

The main interest here is that:

1. The checkbox size stays proportional to the text size
2. You can control the aspect, the color, the size of the checkbox
3. No extra HTML needed !
4. Only 3 lines of CSS needed (the last one is just to give you ideas)

**Edit**:
As pointed out in the comment, the checkbox won't be accessible by key navigation. You should probably add `tabindex=0` as a property for your label to make it focusable.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `display:none` on input will prevent it from being selected with `tab` key so I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Good remark. You could add tabindex=0 on the input to fix this.

Comment: I wonder if all those CSS rules may confuse some accessibility features?

Answer (score 28):

Preview:
http://jsfiddle.net/h4qka9td/

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.switch {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.switch label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.switch input {
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* DEMO 3 */

.switch.demo3 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}

.switch.demo3 label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #a5a39d;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow:
      inset 0 3px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
      0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.switch.demo3 label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -8px; right: -8px; bottom: -8px; left: -8px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #ababab;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #ababab);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #ababab);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #ababab);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f2f2f2), to(#ababab));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #ababab);
  background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #ababab);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
        0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.switch.demo3 label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -18px; right: -18px; bottom: -18px; left: -18px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #eee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e5e7e6, #eee);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#e5e7e6, #eee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#e5e7e6, #eee);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#e5e7e6), to(#eee));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e5e7e6, #eee);
  background: linear-gradient(#e5e7e6, #eee);
  box-shadow:
      0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.switch.demo3 label i {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: silver;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 40%;
  top: 0;
  background: #b2ac9e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f7f2f6), to(#b2ac9e));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
  background: linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
  box-shadow:
      inset 0 1px 0 white,
      0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
      0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.switch.demo3 label i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #d2cbc3;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#cbc7bc, #d2cbc3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#cbc7bc, #d2cbc3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#cbc7bc, #d2cbc3);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#cbc7bc), to(#d2cbc3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cbc7bc, #d2cbc3);
  background: linear-gradient(#cbc7bc, #d2cbc3);
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.switch.demo3 label i:before {
  content: "off";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #bcb8ae, 0 -1px 0 #97958e;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  right: -50%;
}

.switch.demo3 input:checked ~ label {
  background: #9abb82;
}

.switch.demo3 input:checked ~ label i {
  right: -1%;
}

.switch.demo3 input:checked ~ label i:before {
  content: "on";
  right: 115%;
  color: #82a06a;
  text-shadow: 
    0 1px 0 #afcb9b,
    0 -1px 0 #6b8659;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch demo3">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label><i></i>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="switch demo3">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <label><i></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @robertjd agreed, was confused about why this would be needed for a simple transform

Comment: @robertjd Those aren't even checkboxes; they're toggles.

Answer (score 21):

The appearance of checkboxes seems to be fixed by default. But as pointed out by Worthy7 this can be remedied using [CSS `appearance` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance). It will make checkboxes completely empty, so you can define your own appearance. What is nice about this: You can use your existing HTML code. Downside: It is [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental). Edge (legacy) and IE do not use the custom style.

Here are the needed CSS styles:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 14mm;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 14mm;
    border: 0.1mm solid black;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    margin-left: 4.3mm;
    margin-top: -0.4mm;
    width: 3mm;
    height: 10mm;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 2mm 2mm 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> Test</label>
```

Screenshots:

Chrome: [image]

Firefox: [image]

Edge: [image]

Edge (legacy): [image]

IE: [image]

Answer (score 11):

This should work

```
input {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

It worked for me for Firefox and Chrome and iPhone's Firefox, Chrome and Safari at least.

Answer (score 10):

I think the simplest solution is re-style the checkbox as some users suggest. The CSS below is working for me, only requires a few lines of CSS, and answers the OP question:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 14px; 
    height: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 1px;
    color: blue;
    content: "\2713"; /* check mark */
}
```

As mentioned in this post, the zoom property seems not to work on Firefox, and transforms may cause undesired effects.

Tested on Chrome and Firefox, should work for all modern browsers. Just change the properties (colors, size, bottom, left, etc.) to your needs. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

I was looking to make a checkbox that was just a little bit larger and looked at the source code for 37Signals Basecamp to find the following solution-

You can change the font size to make the checkbox slightly larger:

```
font-size: x-large;
```

Then, you can align the checkbox properly by doing:

```
vertical-align: top;
margin-top: 3px; /* change to center it */
```

Comment: font-size doesn't seem to affect the size of the actual checkbox at all

Answer (score 7):

You can make checkboxes larger in Safari — which is generally resistant to the usual approaches — with this attribute: `-webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);`

[Source](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=89167)

Answer (score 6):

My reputation is slightly too low to post comments, but I made a modification to Jack Miller's code above in order to get it to not change size when you check and uncheck it. This was causing text alignment problems for me.

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
        width: 17px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        height: 17px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        background-color: #F58027;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
        margin-left: 4px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        width: 4px;
        height: 12px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:after {
        margin-left: 4px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        width: 4px;
        height: 12px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> Test</label>
```

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that this isn't easy at all to do cross-browser. Instead of trying to manipulate the checkbox control, you could always build your own implementation using images, javascript, and hidden input fields. I'm assuming this is similar to what niceforms is (from Staicu lonut's answer above), but wouldn't be particularly difficult to implement. I believe jQuery has a plugin to allow for this custom behavior as well (will look for the link and post here if I can find it).

Answer (score 5):

**use this css code**

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(1.5); /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.5);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this CSS-only library to be very helpful:
https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Or, you could roll your own with this same basic concept, similar to what @Sharcoux posted. It's basically:

- Hide the normal checkbox (opacity 0 and placed where it would go)
- Add a css-based fake checkbox
- Use `input:checked~div label` for the checked style
- make sure your `<label>` is clickable using `for=yourinputID`

```css
.pretty {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}
.pretty input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pretty-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.pretty-inner label {
  position: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
  min-width: calc(1em + 2px);
}
.pretty-inner label:after,
.pretty-inner label:before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(1em + 2px);
  height: calc(1em + 2px);
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.pretty-inner label:before {
  border-color: #bdc3c7;
}
.pretty input:checked~.pretty-inner label:after {
  background-color: #00bb82;
  width: calc(1em - 6px);
  height: calc(1em - 6px);
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}


/* Add checkmark character style */
.pretty input:checked~.pretty-inner.checkmark:after {
  content: '\2713';
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  left: 6px;
  top: 3px;
}



body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="pretty">
 <input type="checkbox" id="demo" name="demo">
 <div class="pretty-inner"><label for="demo">I agree.</label></div>
</div>

<div class="pretty">
 <input type="checkbox" id="demo" name="demo">
 <div class="pretty-inner checkmark"><label for="demo">Please check the box.</label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers showed a pixelated checkbox, while I wanted something beautiful.
The result looks like this:
[image: checkbox preview]

Even though this version is more complicated I think it's worth giving it a try.

```css
.checkbox-list__item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 34px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b4bcc2;
}
.checkbox-list__item:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.checkbox-list__check {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 3px solid #b4bcc2;
  position: absolute;
  left: -34px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  transition: border .3s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.checkbox-list__check:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 22px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
  content: '\2713';
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .checkbox-list__check {
  border-color: #5bc0de;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .checkbox-list__check:before {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-list__item">
  <input class="checkbox_buttons" type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
  <div class="checkbox-list__check"></div>
</label>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asbd4hpr/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is Firefox doesn't listen to width and height. Disable that and your good to go.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> Test</label>
```

Comment: This simply makes the entire checkbox disappear. You then have to provide a background color to see it. But then how do you make the check mark appear? This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Put the checkbox inside a parent with *display:grid* and make sure it doesn't have *margin:auto*

https://codepen.io/sneffel/pen/oNPYvBx

```css
 body{
     text-align:center;
}
 .grid{
    display:grid;
}
 input{
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="first">
</div>
<form class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="second">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height and width in the code below

```css
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ff7e02;
}
```

```html
<div class="check">

     <label class="container1">Architecture/Landscape
                                          

    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                                          

    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                 

    </label>
</div>
```