# Increasing the size of checkbox in HTML

Tags: html

Is there any way to increase the size of checkbox in HTML?

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size of checkbox in CSS or javascript?

Comment: A lot of really helpful ideas posted here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/306924/469643

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not in an easy cross browser way.

You would get the most flexibility replacing it with a control that utilises JavaScript and CSS. Use a standard checkbox as a fallback.

These days, with the `:checked` pseudo selector, you can make a `label` element to do it as well.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size of checkbox in CSS or javascript?

Comment: Don't use JS. You could consider [this link](http://www.jotform.org/html-elements/how-to-change-checkbox-size-css/). It' a very interesting workaround, as suggested by @Sjoerd

Answer (score 37):

One way I changed the checkbox size is by scaling it with CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Simple and useful in many cases where all you're trying to do is match the font size.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="checked()" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

No. Most browsers ignore the width or height CSS styling of a checkbox. There are two ways around that:

- Use a `label` tag so that clicking some other element also triggers the textbox.
- Make your own checkbox using Javascript, by switching an image and filling a hidden input box.

Answer (score 6):

A trick for increasing size of HTML checkbox is increase zoom property of input.
It is cross browser compatible and also it will adjust the size according to resolution of device.

```css
.daysCheckbox1{
zoom:1;

}
.daysCheckbox2{
zoom:1.5;

}
.daysCheckbox3{
zoom:2;

}
.daysCheckbox4{
zoom:2.5;

}
```

```html
<label> Checkbox 1<input type="checkbox" class="daysCheckbox1"   name="Monday"></label><Br>
<label> Checkbox 2<input type="checkbox" class="daysCheckbox2"   name="Monday"></label><Br>
<label> Checkbox 3<input type="checkbox" class="daysCheckbox3"   name="Monday"></label><Br>
<label> Checkbox 4<input type="checkbox" class="daysCheckbox4"   name="Monday"></label><Br>
```

Comment: [`zoom` is a non-standard CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) and doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

I searched a lot and finally i created a custom checkbox.Code is

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".CheckBoxClass").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).next("label").addClass("LabelSelected");
    }else{
        $(this).next("label").removeClass("LabelSelected");
    }
});
          });
       </script>
```

Style is

```
     .CheckBoxLabelClass{
    background: url("uncheck222.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 60px;   
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
}
.CheckBoxLabelClass:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.LabelSelected{
     background: url("check1111.png") no-repeat; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 60px;   
    width: 60px;
    display: block;

}
```

checkbox code is:

```
    <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" class="CheckBoxClass"/>
            <label id="Label1" for="CheckBox1" class="CheckBoxLabelClass"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to put the checkbox item inside the div element, change the div element size using px.
Now set the height and width of the checkbox item to 100% of the div element.

```
<style>
    *Reset*
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
   *Changing the height of the body for better view*
    body {
        height: 1000px;
    }
    *Increasing the height and width of the div element*
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: brown;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
  *setting the height and width of the input to 100% of the div element*
    input {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px; /*Desired width*/
  height: 50px; /*Desired height*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

OR

```css
.CbxSizer {
  zoom: 8;
  transform: scale(4);
  -ms-transform: scale(4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="CbxSizer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hello" value="1">
</div>
```

OR

```css
    input[type='checkbox'] {
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        background:white;
        border-radius:6px;
        border:3px solid #445;
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:checked {
        background: #abd;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score -5):

U can create a custom checkbox with 2 images switching with each other on tou

Comment: What exactly do you mean, how would you do it? Show some code. The answer in this form doesn't contribute enough. Mention me in a comment after edit so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score -5):

Set the font-size of the checkbox to something like 5em. Worked for me.