# How to size input[type=checkbox] elements using css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

We have been sizing checkboxes using transform:scale(1.5) for sometime.  Recently something has changed in the browsers, because it is no longer working.  For example on Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) updated today (4/30/15), the following code doesn't work.  The size jumps to about 3X.  Changing the scale number (for example to 1.1) has no effect.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.5)">
</body>
</html>
```

So, does anyone know how to size a checkbox using current browsers?  I've tried all the solutions I have read about (font-size:x-large, setting height, width, font-size, ...)

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242240/increasing-the-size-of-checkbox-in-html

Answer (score 2):

It's notoriously difficult to style checkbox elements. I tend to hide the checkbox itself, introducing a sibling element to show the state instead. Simplifed / redacted code from something I worked on:

**Markup**

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox__icon"></span>
</label>
```

**SASS**

```
.checkbox {
    .checkbox__icon {
        /* styling for checkbox goes here */
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
        &:checked ~ .checkbox__icon {
            /* styling for checked checkbox goes here */
        }
        &:disabled ~ .checkbox__icon {
            /* styling for disabled checkbox goes here */
        }
    }
}
```

The span can contain a font-icon, an svg background image, whatever you like. But regardless of the approach you take, the upshot is that you can control how it looks across browsers.

Comment: Cool.  I don't know SASS.  Is &:checked ~ .checkbox__icon standard css syntax or something specific to SASS?  I haven't seen & in standard css before.

Comment: & is specific to sass, it extends the parent selector, so that's basically targeting input[type=checkbox]:checked. ~ is standard CSS, it's a sibling selector.

Answer (score 0):

Label text may need re-aligning with this increase in size:

```
(.large-check) input[type=checkbox] {
    height: 20px ;
    width: 20px  ;
}
```