# Create CSS to enlarge checkboxes

Tags: css, resize, label, checkbox

I am trying to double the size of my checkboxes on a few pages.  How do I make that happen in CSS?  I don't want to style the hover.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always use the checkbox hack to make your own checkbox. This allows for a much more cross browser compatible solution.

I made a quick demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EZHwR/1/), obviously you would have to get a transparent .png of a tick, not the one I got.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div label{
    background: url(http://ramyasspace.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/tick.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

---

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label input[type=checkbox] ~ span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

label input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
  /* image: Picol.org, cc-by 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Accept_Picol_icon.svg */
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M14 18L26 6l4 4-16 16L4 16l4-4z"/></svg>');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Click me:
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I love it!!  It actually works quite well in a lot of browsers.  Question for you though:  How do I get it check?  It isn't working with the code you gave me...

Comment: How is it not checking? What browser? It should do, the label gets :checked when the checkbox does, and vice versa.

Comment: Please, don't override checkboxes if you want to keep your sanity.

Comment: As "cross browser" as does not work on Opera Mini. -1

Comment: Using images is rather a heavyweight solution for this simple problem.

Answer (score 50):

To double the size of checkboxes, you can use the CSS scale property. The (2,2) means 2 times the width and 2 times the height of the original, but this will be quite large.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  transform:scale(2, 2);
}
```

You can also use decimal values, for just slightly bigger checkboxes.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
      transform:scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but scale will not work on all browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: Be careful with using scale. To support all browsers you should do much more: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css

Comment: Really pixilated. Not ideal solution imho.

Answer (score 13):

This works. It uses relative sizes so it scales with your current font size.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
}
```

You may need to adjust your margins though.

Answer (score 11):

Styling checkboxes is risky business. It's one of those things that never seems to work consistently with all browsers.

or you can try with

```
 style="zoom:1.2"
```

jQuery offers a [plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox) to do a replacement on checkboxes

Comment: This one didn't work for me.  Am I supposed to style the input element?

Comment: Yes you can give it a try but I would not recommend that as it will be inconsistent in different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can do is give it a bigger font-size. From there it's up to how the browser handles it unless you make a mock div element that controls a hidden checkbox. It doesn't scale it up that much.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a cross-browser issue with this as well (as my suggestion below).

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library with sucess

http://plugins.krajee.com/checkbox-x

It requires jQuery and bootstrap 3.x

Download the zip here: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-checkbox-x/zipball/master

Put the contents of the zip in a folder within your project

Pop the needed libs in your header

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="path/to/css/checkbox-x.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/js/checkbox-x.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the data controls to the element using the data-size="xl" to change the size as shown here http://plugins.krajee.com/cbx-sizes-demo

```
<label for="element_id">CheckME</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_element" id="element_id" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox-x" data-three-state="false" data-size="xl"/>
```

There are numerous other features as well if you browse the plugin site.

Comment: Great, but something without Bootstrap would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Styling checkbox's is a very wierd world full off cross browser issues. More info can be found here http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/ You can also create your own with javascript but this is not great for user accessibility.

So I would tray an avoid changing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add background image to checkbox. And adjust the sizes as you prefer.

The code below automatically adds background when it's **checked**, and the size remains the same with **unchecked** status.

No need to specify like:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked
```

**or**

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div label
```

**For ex, all checkboxes**:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  background: url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_full.png');
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ac5f2ob/).

Answer (score -1):

Or simply style it with height and width like this:

```
<input style="height: 26px; width:26px; margin-left:-30px" value="" type="checkbox">
```

PS. I have used this with bootstrap and the "checkbox-inline" class

Comment: Works fine with Crome and IE. Seems to be an issue with Firefox and Safari, so I guess you´re right.