# How can I change the size of a Bootstrap checkbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Wondering if its possible to change the size of checkbox as it's possible with buttons. I want it to be bigger, so it makes it easy to press. Right now its looking like this:

[image]

Code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Kalsiumklorid: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5" >
      {{ Form::checkbox('O_Kals_Klor', 1 , array('class' => 'form-control' ))  }}  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate, take a look at this, can help you out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631537/create-css-to-enlarge-checkboxes

Comment: Do you mean "as it's possible with **buttons**"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805394/how-to-change-size-of-icheck-checkbox-and-add-border-radius/57805647?noredirect=1#comment102043290_57805647

Answer (score 62):

Or you can style it with pixels.

```
 .big-checkbox {width: 30px; height: 30px;}
```

Comment: works in chrome but not in firefox :( stopped testing there.

Comment: @John I use this just for mobile since the default checkbox size is too small for a finger to comfortably tap it, and it worked on the mobile browsers I've tried.

Comment: @John Thanks to you, I didn't bother trying this one. I just added extra space on top and bottom of the checkbox to make it noticeable.

Comment: Forcing a width/height does work in Firefox, but you need to set both, else you'll just get a padded gap of the width/height you set.

Answer (score 47):

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thats a good solution, but I have problems with the spacing between checkbox and label.

Comment: just but 1 or 2  &nbsp;  before label :-)

Comment: This creates issues with checkboxes on Chrome for iPhone, they become a few times to large. Any ideas how to solve for that?

Comment: Works quite well, but pixelates a little during the animation on Safari (Mac).

Comment: The problem I have noticed with just using `scale` is that it also increases the thickness of the checkbox borders, which is not always desirable.

Comment: @BSUK I have the same issue, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/html-viewer/b99672006e60).

Answer (score 14):

It is possible in css, but not for all the browsers.

The effect on all browsers:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/

A possibility is a custom checkbox with javascript:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: Thanks, with javascript how do I increase the size of this checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/M5B3a/

Answer (score 12):

Following works in bootstrap 4 and displays well in CSS, mobile and has no issues with label spacing.

[image]

**CSS**

```
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before, 
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  top: .8rem;
  width: 1.55rem;
  height: 1.55rem;
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}


.checkbox-xl .custom-control-label::before, 
.checkbox-xl .custom-control-label::after {
  top: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.85rem;
  height: 1.85rem;
}

.checkbox-xl .custom-control-label {
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-3">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-3">Large checkbox</label>
    </div>
```

You can also make it extra large by declaring `checkbox-xl`

If anyone from BS team is reading this, it would be really good if you make this available right out of the box, I don't see anything for it in BS 5 either

[source](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/820928#html-tab-view)

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to implement custom bootstrap checkbox for the most popular browsers nowadays.

You can check my [Bootstrap-Checkbox](https://github.com/Artur-A/Bootstrap-Checkbox) project in GitHub, which contains simple [.less file](https://github.com/Artur-A/Bootstrap-Checkbox/blob/master/checkbox-bootstrap.less).
There is a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms) in MDN describing some techniques, where the two major are:

1. Label redirects a click event.

   Label can redirect a click event to its target if it has the `for` attribute like  in   `<label for="target_id">Text</label> <input id="target_id" type="checkbox" />`, or if it contains input as in Bootstrap case: `<label><input type="checkbox" />Text</label>`.

   It means that it is possible to place a label in one corner of the browser, click on it, and then the label will redirect click event to the checkbox located in other corner producing check/uncheck action for the checkbox.

   We can *hide original checkbox visually*, but make it is still working and *taking click event from the label*. In the label itself we can emulate checkbox with a tag or pseudo-element `:before :after`.
2. General non supported tag for old browsers

   Some old browsers does not support several CSS features like selecting siblings `p+p` or specific search `input[type=checkbox]`. According to the MDN article browsers that support these features also support `:root` CSS selector, while others not. The `:root` selector just selects the root element of a document, which is `html` in a HTML page. Thus it is possible to use `:root` for a fallback to old browsers and original checkboxes.

   Final code snippet:

```css
:root {
  /* larger checkbox */
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox] {
  /* hide original check box */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* find the nearest span with checkbox-placeholder class and draw custom checkbox */
  /* draw checkmark before the span placeholder when original hidden input is checked */
  /* disabled checkbox style */
  /* disabled and checked checkbox style */
  /* when the checkbox is focused with tab key show dots arround */
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox] + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*checkbox border color*/
  border-color: #737373;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 7px 0 -20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  background: #0ccce4;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.checkbox-placeholder:before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 5px;
  height: 9px;
  /*checkmark arrow color*/
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  /*can be done with post css autoprefixer*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: "";
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox]:disabled + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  background: #ececec;
  border-color: #c3c2c2;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  background: #d6d6d6;
  border-color: #bdbdbd;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap input[type=checkbox]:focus:not(:hover) + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap.checkbox-lg input[type=checkbox] + span.checkbox-placeholder {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*checkbox border color*/
  border-color: #737373;
}
:root label.checkbox-bootstrap.checkbox-lg input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.checkbox-placeholder:before {
  width: 9px;
  height: 15px;
  /*checkmark arrow color*/
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
 Original checkboxes:
</p>
<div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-bootstrap">                                        
          <input type="checkbox">             
          <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
          Original checkbox
      </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-bootstrap">                                        
          <input type="checkbox" disabled>             
          <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
          Original checkbox disabled
      </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-bootstrap">                                        
          <input type="checkbox" checked>             
          <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
          Original checkbox checked
      </label>
 </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-bootstrap">                                        
          <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>             
          <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
          Original checkbox checked and disabled
      </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-lg">                           
          <input type="checkbox">             
          <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
          Large checkbox unchecked
      </label>
 </div>
  <br/>
<p>
 Inline checkboxes:
</p>
<label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-bootstrap">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
  Inline 
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-bootstrap">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled>
  <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
  Inline disabled
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-bootstrap">
  <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
  <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
  Inline checked and disabled
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
  Large inline checked
</label>
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff. Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I used just "save in zoom", in example:

```
.my_checkbox {
    width:5vw;
    height:5vh;
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective answer

Comment: this doesn't work very well for mobile viewports

Answer (score 4):

just use simple css

```
.big-checkbox {width: 1.5rem; height: 1.5rem;top:0.5rem}
```

Comment: Cheers for using `rem`s and not `px` units ...

Answer (score 2):

I have used this library with sucess

http://plugins.krajee.com/checkbox-x

It requires jQuery and bootstrap 3.x

Download the zip here: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-checkbox-x/zipball/master

Put the contents of the zip in a folder within your project

Pop the needed libs in your header

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="path/to/css/checkbox-x.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/js/checkbox-x.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the data controls to the element using the data-size="xl" to change the size as shown here http://plugins.krajee.com/cbx-sizes-demo

```
<label for="element_id">CheckME</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_element" id="element_id" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox-x" data-three-state="false" data-size="xl"/>
```

There are numerous other features as well if you browse the plugin site.

Answer (score 2):

> Aqui lo que me ayudo a solucionarlo:

```css
.checkbox-xl .form-check-input 
{
    scale: 2.5;
}
.checkbox-xl .form-check-label 
{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check checkbox-xl">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox-3" name="check1"/>
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-3">Etiqueta</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="rr-element">
   <label for="rr-1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
      Value 1
   </label>
</div>
//do this on the css
div label input { margin-right:100px; }
```