# Rails make checkbox more visible

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a Rails app with Bootstrap.

I use this code to display boolean data as checkboxes in views:

```
<td class='bigcheckbox'><%= check_box_tag 'm_people', '1', menucontrol.m_people, disabled: true %></td>
```

The checkbox shows up small and grey instead of black.

I'm trying to make it larger and bold looking.

This is the css:

```
.bigcheckbox {
  width: 20px!important;
  height: 20px!important;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question was answered here: [Size of checkbox bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743457/size-of-checkbox-bootstrap)

The answer was:

> It is possible in css, but not for all the browser.
>
> The effect on all browsers:
>
> http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/
>
> A possibility is a custom checkbox with javascript:
>
> http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/