# Checkbox align with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a checkbox with class="form-control", I note that the checkbox is centered inside the form-control border, how to left align it:

My HTML code is:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" style="margin: 0px 0px 0 !important;" id="txtPEPFlag" name="txtPEPFlag" value="Y">
```

It appears as (IE9):

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" style="margin-right:30px!important;;" id="txtPEPFlag" name="txtPEPFlag" value="Y">
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox doesn't work well when you give it form-control class, check here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms
In the example they put it inside a checkbox class div:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need it to be same height as Input (37px), so i need a big checkbox

Comment: @ImadAbuHayyah you can do that like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631537/create-css-to-enlarge-checkboxes  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743457/size-of-checkbox-bootstrap

Comment: In that link, it not appear that it will resize on other browsers or tablets, I need it to be dynamic

Comment: may be try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css

Answer (score 0):

try to use the grid columns from bootstrap