# How to reduce the size of the checkbox in the ipad borwser (chrome and safari)?

Tags: ios, css, ipad, ios8.3

Is it possible to reduce the size of the checkbox in the ipad browsers.It is showing big in the browser.

Comment: jsfiddle? or site where you are facing this issue?

Comment: Leo  i am facing this issue in my application works fine in web but coming to ipad it is displaying very big.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox size in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css)

Comment: it is hard to solve your issue without any demo/jsfiddle or link as we are totally blind so anything which you can share, please..