# Change size of checkboxes in cells of bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and a [column with checkboxes](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#checkbox-table). How can I change size of checkboxes. In my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/103/) i want checkbox size 25x25, but when I use height and width css attributes it doesn't work.

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-formatter="starsFormatter"></th>
        <th data-field="name" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count" data-formatter="starsFormatter" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count" data-formatter="forksFormatter" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
var data = [{name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
});

function starsFormatter(row, value, inde) {
    return row + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> ';
}

function forksFormatter(value) {
    return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></i> ' + value;
}
```

**css**

```
.bs-checkbox input{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Try using `!important` to force the style: `{
width:25px!important;
height:25px!imporant; }`

Comment: @Zealander I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: When I tested this it worked fine; you should probably post a working example of the problem in a Snippet.

Comment: @vanburenx here is snippet http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/106/

Comment: This works in IE & Chrome, not in Firefox. This is a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css?s=6|0.7482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.bs-checkbox input
{
    zoom:2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and easy way to do it**

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
transform:scale(x,y);
}
```

> **x,y can be any value depends upon how much large box you want**