# CSS Increase Checkbox Size without Increasing Text Size

Tags: html, css, web-applications, resize, hiccup

I have the following HTML code (it's Hiccup HTML, a [library created by weavejester](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup), which allows HTML to be written in Clojure, enclosed in vectors) :

```
    [:div#permissionsRequired
    [:input {:type "checkbox"} "No permissions required"]]
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
    #permissionsRequired{
    margin-left: 45vw;
    margin-top: -15vw;
    padding-bottom: 5vw;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    width: 20vw;
    }
```

I want to increase the width and height of the checkbox without increasing the size of the text beside it.

Is this possible using simple CSS?

Thank you.

Comment: that's not html code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is HTML code, written using a Clojure library called Hiccup that allows HTML to be written in Clojure when wrapped in vectors. Follow the link for an explanation.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css

Comment: How do you propose shortening this code Paulie_D?

Comment: This question is a solution for every checkbox on the page, not just one specific one which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.format_chkbox{
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<input class="format_chkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Above I've Provided an very simple example which seems to be help for you.

Below I've also Attached : OUTPUT image(screenshot)

---

[Output to above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQYly.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know that would work. I was wondering if anyone knows of simple CSS to increase the size of a checkbox. I know I could create another CSS class fro it entirely, but I'm only seeing if there's a short CSS answer.