# Why does the Checkbox look like that?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

https://test.terminbuch.eu/massimo/termine

After you click "Registrieren", on the right you see a very small checkbox.
It doesn't look like a normal checkbox. And its very small, although the Developer Tools show no rules for checkboxes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use `display: inline-flex` on the `.checkbox` class. Specify a flex attribute for the checkbox input element and it will work:

```
.checkbox-cb {
    margin-right: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You are right! I haven't even noticed the `inline-flex` as it doesn't make any sense to use flexbox in this situation...

Answer (score 1):

add `width:100px;` in `framework.css` at line number 106 and class name `.checkbox-cb`. it will helps you.

you need to change below listed class.

```
.checkbox-cb {
    margin-right: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal checkbox. It's 13px x 13px in Firefox which is the default checkbox size on this browser. I've isolated the code below so that you can play with it in different browsers:

```css
.agbCheckbox {
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-cb {
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="agbCheckbox checkbox" id="77">
  <input class="checkbox-cb" id="77-cb" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkbox-text" id="77-text">Den Inhalt der <a id="agbLink" href="">AGB und Datenschutzerklärung</a> habe ich zur Kenntnis genommen und erkläre mich damit einverstanden.</span>
</div>
```

If you want to change the checkbox size with only CSS there is a good topic here on SO: [Checkbox size in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css)

Comment: I think it doesn't reproduce the problem, because the checkbox is not as tiny as on his website...