# Shiny checkboxGroup change size of box

Tags: r, shiny

Running into a css issue with Shiny's checkboxgroup. The below code changes the text size next to the boxes but unfortunately the boxes do not change with it.

Any recommendation as how to change the box size (height & width)?

```
tags$style("#EQUITY_show_vars {font-size:10px;height:10px;}"),
             checkboxGroupInput('EQUITY_show_vars', 'Equity:',
                          ETF_Names[1:5], selected = ETF_Names[1:4],inline=TRUE),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css#10415275) you can do something like:

```
tags$style("input[type=checkbox] {
                    transform: scale(.8);
           }"),

tags$style("#EQUITY_show_vars {
                    font-size:10px;
                    height:10px;
           }"),
checkboxGroupInput('EQUITY_show_vars', 'Equity:',
                    ETF_Names[1:5], selected = ETF_Names[1:4],inline=TRUE),
```

Read that answer and use some CSS to adapt the styling to your needs