# Telerik Radgrid RenderMode not working on Mobile

Tags: vb.net, mobile, telerik, radgrid

I am working with a project which is based on web form with vb.net,I used telerik radgrid for data binding.
I placed `RenderMode="Auto"` into radgrid.
When run on desktop, it working properly.
But when run on mobile device,grid not showing.
I want to allow multiselect row option for mobile as well as desktop.
So I add rendermode for working on both desktop and mobile.
Also I have follow the rule https://www.telerik.com/forums/rendermode=-auto.
Please suggest me the What I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set the RenderMode property to Lightweight (this mode also works properly on mobile) and to enable the checkbox column (<telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>) which will allow you to select multiple rows both on mobile and desktop as shown in the following demo:

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx

As a hint, you can increase the checkbox size with the following CSS class:
[Checkbox size in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/checkbox-size-in-html-css)

@supports (zoom:2) {
    input[type="radio"],  input[type=checkbox]{
    zoom: 2;
    }
}
@supports not (zoom:2) {
    input[type="radio"],  input[type=checkbox]{
        transform: scale(2);
        margin: 15px;
    }
}
label{
  /* fix vertical align issues */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
}