# Increasing the height of the content in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a checkbox in my angular app. when the value is checked, the box is filled with the value in google-chrome. in firefox it is displaying only on top corner instead of filling the input field. How can i resolve this. please guide me.

HTML

```
<input class="customInput" id="custom" type="checkbox" formControlName="test" readonly>
```

css

```
.customInput {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

// fully checked in chrome

// uncompatable firefox
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the checkbox size using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306924/can-i-change-the-checkbox-size-using-css)

Comment: I have problem with the size of the content not with the size of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Browsers react very differently,**

In Chrome broswer it shows perfectly,

[image]

But in Firefox 57 shows,

[image]

More info :  Visit [styling checkbox in different browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling#Styling_checkboxes_and_radio_buttons)