# Should I put input elements inside a label element?

Tags: html, semantics

Is there a best practice concerning the nesting of `label` and `input` HTML elements?

classic way:

```html
<label for="myinput">My Text</label>
<input type="text" id="myinput" />
```

or

```html
<label for="myinput">My Text
   <input type="text" id="myinput" />
</label>
```

Comment: One of the big pros of putting the `<input />` inside the `<label>`, is that you can omit `for` and `id`: `<label>My text <input /></label>` in your example. So much nicer!

Comment: While I agree that `input` does not semantically belong inside of a `label`, I noticed today that the [developers of Bootstrap disagree with me](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls). Some elements, such as inline checkboxes, are styled differently depending on whether the `input` is inside or out.

Comment: BTW this was a really bad idea to create `<label for="id">` as I have multiple forms on the page and I can not use `id` attribute for many widgets without falling in `unique id per page` trap. The only acceptable way to access the widget is by `form + widget_name`.

Comment: @MaxZoom if you have so many different forms on your page with identical field names that you're having trouble coming up with unique IDs, you might want to reconsider your page design a little, IMHO; obviously I don't know your situation, but that just [smells bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me

Comment: @kenbellows It is a designer/business (not my) idea to put two Search forms on one page. The best user experience practices may change over time but the HTML should be flexible enough (IMHO)  to cover any visible scenario.

Comment: @kenbellows I do not think of this as a code smell.  ASP.NET MVC's Html helpers (Html.EditFor, etc...) are able to come up with reasonable names /ids based on the datamodel (not perfect for sure).  Unless you roll something like that for client side (eg, knockout), using partial views or repeating controls will immediately hit this issue.  If I have something repeating, it becomes very contextual as to how to create unique ids and IMO doesn't really add any value.

Comment: One sidenote (regarding @Znarkus comment) "The label element may contain at most one button, input, keygen, meter, output, progress, select, or textarea descendant."

Comment: @Blazemonger Semantically speaking, label acts as a control for focus, so for checkboxes&radio buttons that are selected by square area around them - it is a correct use. Though I agree there should be a special "control" element only

Comment: The second way brings about Jsoup parsing problems. I cannot get the value of input in this label, neither with `inputElement.val()` nor `labelElement.val()`. Big issue here....

Comment: @kenbellows I disagree it's a code smell. There are many perfectly valid use cases for reusing forms in a page. As a simple example, a table with in-place editing may have an instance of a single form on each row and potentially in multiple columns. Search functionality within sections of the page is another.

Comment: Keeping `input` inside `label` seem to cause [alignment problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

Answer (score 616, accepted):

From the W3's [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL):

> The label itself may be positioned before, after or around the
> associated control.

---

```html
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
```

or

```html
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
```

or

```html
<label>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" />
   Last Name
</label>
```

Note that the third technique cannot be used when a table is being used for layout, with the label in one cell and its associated form field in another cell.

Either one is valid. I like to use either the first or second example, as it gives you more style control.

Comment: As answered, all are valid but in my own practice I typically settle on the first example given here by superUntitled for textboxes, textareas, and selects. But for radio buttons and checkboxes, I usually use the third example, where I want the input before the accompanying text and don't want the same kind of fixed width and/or floating that the rest of the labels and fields are using. So on any single given form, you might find me using both of these formats together.

Comment: I wonder if `<label for="inputbox"><input id="inputbox" type="text" /></label>` is a pass according to their criteria.

Comment: @FelipeAls not hard to code ? When nesting components in asp.net their id is prefixed with id of all their container 'ancestors'. So you can't easily guess what would be the for value. Of course you would still be able to get this value, but this is needlessly complicated vs label input/ /label construct

Comment: Too bad that you can not nest a label inside an input tag. Would be much more semantically rational, since the label really is a property of the input, if you see it from an abstract point of view.

Comment: @frenchone The ASP.NET `Label` control has an `AssociatedControlID` property that allows you to add an appropriate "for" attribute to a label. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Alex totally agree. would also be cool if labels were automatically prepended to inputs, forever freeing us from the ugliness of labels in forms.

Comment: The linked WCAG document includes the following option "The control is contained within a label element that contains the label text."  I don't know if that was added in the years since @Sorcy commented, but the input-in-label scenario is considered valid now.

Comment: Oh, apparently they changed it. Hooray for sanity!

Comment: Third option is also less error prone. Ever seen a site where there's an input, but clicking it somehow targets a different input element that's not expected? Can be bad if it was for a check-box that's not in view.

Comment: There is an issue with the input inside label, at least in chrome, when you attach a click event handler to the label, the handler gets fired twice when the label is clicked. You can get by this with `return false;` at the end of the handler, but if you possibly have other handlers that need to execute afterwards, and stopping propagation isn't an option, this becomes an issue.

Comment: There is a problem with wrapping `label` around `input`, that's if you want to change the label's style according to the `checked` state of the radio/checkbox, you cannot do so with pure CSS.

Comment: One limitation of the first and last options: they do not allow a pure CSS toggle switch (e.g. http://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/eLIiG). For that, you need the label following the input so that you can use an adjacent sibling selector to style the on/off states of the toggle.

Comment: @FelipeAls & sorcy Can you please remove your comments about #3 not being a valid approach?  This makes things horribly confusing; there are so many up votes for the comment that is no longer true.

Comment: @superUntitled is explain in best way and detailed. it doesn't matter, where you placed on entire page, It should be link via label 'for' attribute and input have same 'ID'. for Example, table on 1 column is having label for and 2 column is having input box.

Comment: @Matt nesting plus id does not work in Firefox v54 and IE11 and Chrome 59.

Comment: One thing to note is that the input must have a "name" attribute in order for clicking the label to focus it.

Comment: @superUntitled another note on the third approach is that it does not work in IE6.

Comment: @Alex: that would also make it possible to style `label` depending on eg. a checkbox is checked etc.

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it seems to say what the OP already knew: That both methods are valid.  The question was about best practices: Why would a person chose one method over another.  Of course, I do see that the OP voted it as the best answer, which is a mystery to me.

Comment: @RandallStewart OP probably selected this as best because it _also_ provided usage guidance, which was the question. At the time of the choice, there were a lot fewer answers as well. Some may be better _now_ but not then.

Comment: @Alex On second thought, if you think about a different analogy: a piece of paper that says "FREE" on it, and then you sit a toaster on the edge of the paper because you want to indicate that the toaster is free for the taking. Labels can also be platforms / containers for what they are labeling. Perhaps inside or outside could make sense.

Comment: The third option (implicit labels) has accessibility issues with screen readers, because assistive technologies [do not correctly handle them](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/ua-notes/html#H90).

Comment: One reason to use the `<input /><label>…</label>` (label after input) method would be to leverage the `:invalid` pseudo-class on all input elements to apply styles to your label, like making it red or bold or putting a warning icon next to it (e.g. `input:invalid + label { color: red }`).

Comment: You could wrap your label text in a span and get the same result: `<label><input /><span>Foo</span></label>` and `label input:invalid + span`

Comment: It can but it shouldn't. Nesting the input inside its label control is what we otherwise call a malformed or more precisely in this case - wrong nesting.

Answer (score 87):

I prefer

```
<label>
  Firstname
  <input name="firstname" />
</label>

<label>
  Lastname
  <input name="lastname" />
</label>
```

over

```
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input name="firstname" id="firstname" />

<label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
<input name="lastname" id="lastname" />
```

Mainly because it makes the HTML more readable. And I actually think my first example is easier to style with CSS, as CSS works very well with nested elements.

But it's a matter of taste I suppose.

---

If you need more styling options, add a span tag.

```
<label>
  <span>Firstname</span>
  <input name="firstname" />
</label>

<label>
  <span>Lastname</span>
  <input name="lastname" />
</label>
```

Code still looks better in my opinion.

Comment: Including the input inside the label is the same as using HTML for layout.

Comment: I like this solution also for cases like this: `<label>Expires after <input name="exp" /> days</label>` (label is before and after the input element)

Comment: I think the last example is - besides the for and id attributes - not really any different from having the label next to the input and both wrapped into a `div`, `li` or what not, is it!?

Comment: @retrovertigo - functionally? No. It just reduces markup, and reduces semantic overuse of terms. We know the input `firstname` should follow the label for `firstname`, but browsers need the declaration. It's all a matter of taste and what YOU think looks best (and is easiest to debug) in your code. I prefer to use nested now, though it took a while for me to get used to it.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks WCAG2.0 AA compliance around implicit labelling, but adding a `for` attribute on the label should fix it again.

Comment: @JamesWestgate Can you please provide a link to where it says that?  From what I can tell, implicit labels are perfectly acceptable with a note that *SOME* AT do not handle it well, while many others handle it fine.

Comment: @MPavlak - a quick look and I found this guidance from w3.org. https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/. I then checked https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html. At the bottom (it is obscure) it says that in order to claim conformance, you need to pass the test criteria, and that specifically states that you should use the for attribute. 

In reality when I last tested this in Apple Voiceover (10% market share screenreaders desktop, 60% market share screenreaders mobile) implicit labels didnt work, so that was another major factor. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JamesWestgate I think the bigger problem is that there are many ways to pass acceptance criteria which do not involve using explicit labels.  By failing to meet acceptance H44 does not mean you are not in some other way (eg, title or aria attributes) meeting accessibility.  Or am I not understanding that correctly?

Comment: @MPavlak - specifically title is a big no no in accessibility. I can link articles about that if you like, or just google it ;) Just do not use it is your best option.

If you can use a label, use a label. If there is an implicit label, adding a for attribute vs adding an aria tag is going to give you a better result. But if you cant add the label (eg backend issues) then fallback to using aria attributes.

Comment: The interest of that solution is to be able to use CSS pseudo-selector :focus-within on the label to highlight it when the associated input is focused.

Answer (score 66):

**Behavior difference: clicking in the space between label and input**

If you click on the space *between* the label and the input it activates the input only if the label contains the input.

This makes sense since in this case the space is just another character of the label.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
input {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Inside:</p>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  Label. Click between me and the checkbox.
</label>

<p>Outside:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check">Label. Click between me and the checkbox.</label>
```

Being able to click between label and box means that it is:

- easier to click
- less clear where things start and end

Bootstrap checkbox v3.3 examples use the input inside: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms Might be wise to follow them. But they changed their minds in v4.0 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios so I don't know what is wise anymore:

> Checkboxes and radios use are built to support HTML-based form validation and provide concise, accessible labels. As such, our `<input>`s and `<label>`s are sibling elements as opposed to an `<input>` within a `<label>`. This is slightly more verbose as you must specify id and for attributes to relate the `<input>` and `<label>`.

UX question that discusses this point in detail: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23552/should-the-space-between-the-checkbox-and-label-be-clickable

Comment: This isn't a spec difference. The toggle works for both cases in all compliant browsers.

Comment: @hexalys Thanks for the report. I've updated the answer. Do you mean compliant browsers should toggle or not on both cases? If you could link to the relevant standard passage that would be awesome.

Comment: As long as an explicit `for` attribute is associated with an input type, it shall focus and/or toggle on modern browsers (see [compat](http://www.thecssninja.com/talks/abuse_checkboxes/#/17)). There are few browser exceptions though such as iOS that need a [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6472181/1647538).

Comment: @hexalys are we talking about the same thing: cliking *between* label and input checkbox?

Comment: Yes. Though I failed to notice that your example is misleading because your space isn't really a *text space*. It's a `margin` of the checkbox. The Firefox behavior on your example is peculiar and seems like a bug. A `label` will contain the spaces or padding around inline content as clickable. But given that a label's Content model is inline/[Phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) the margin of input shouldn't be clickable, unless your label is made `display: block` in which case the inside of the label `block` become clickable in all browsers.

Comment: Note that the Bootstrap link in the answer goes to the docs for v3.3.  The [docs for v4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios) seem to indicate they've changed their mind: "Checkboxes and radios use are built to support HTML-based form validation and provide concise, accessible labels. As such, our <input>s and <label>s are sibling elements as opposed to an <input> within a <label>. This is slightly more verbose as you must specify id and for attributes to relate the <input> and <label>".

Comment: This behavior difference is the big one for me. When the elements are siblings, any margin on either element **reduces the clickable surface area** that'll trigger the input element. Nesting the input inside the label preserves the maximum clickable area, giving maximum accessibility even for users that struggle with precise mouse or touch movements. In Bootstrap 4, nesting **does still work** and still displays the same without needing to adjust or override any Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 44):

If you include the input tag in the label tag, you don't need to use the 'for' attribute.

That said, I don't like to include the input tag in my labels because I think they're separate, not containing, entities.

Comment: The for requires you to use an id though, which makes structuring the layout hierarchically very hard :-(

Comment: @lethalman - You can always take a leaf from BEM's book, and just namespace the id's... `form-name--control-name`, then you can have things like; `contact-form--email`, and `login-form--email` on the same page, no thought required!

Answer (score 19):

Personally I like to keep the label outside, like in your second example.  That's why the FOR attribute is there.  The reason being I'll often apply styles to the label, like a width, to get the form to look nice (shorthand below):

```
<style>
label {
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>

<label for="myinput">My Text</label>
<input type="text" id="myinput" /><br />
<label for="myinput2">My Text2</label>
<input type="text" id="myinput2" />
```

Makes it so I can avoid tables and all that junk in my forms.

Comment: Shouldn't you leave presentation to CSS, instead of using `<br />` to separate the inputs?

Comment: @Znarkus - yes, normally I wrap them in OL/LIs to deal with formatting like that, this was just a quick shorthand example.

Comment: @Parrots: That doesn't make much sense semantically, imo. And if you need to wrap them, why not just wrap them with the label?

Comment: @Znarkus it's an ordered list of fields you want the user to fill out, right? If you want the labels to appear to the left and be fixed-width (UX of positioning labels to the left or above the field aside), keeping the inputs outside the label avoids the need for fixed positioning.

Comment: @Parrots With that reasoning I think everything on a page should go inside ul/li. And with `<label> <span>My text</span> <input /> </label>` you have all the styling options you'd (ever) need.

Comment: @Znarkus Ah, sure, the inclusion of the span tag will fix the width thing for you.

Comment: Using "for" enforces you to use an id, which is bad for hierarchical layouts.

Answer (score 18):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9 for the W3 recommendations.

They say it can be done either way. They describe the two methods as explicit (using "for" with the element's id) and implicit (embedding the element in the label):

Explicit:

> The for attribute associates a label with another control explicitly: the value of the for attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of the associated control element.

Implicit:

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this case, the LABEL may only contain one control element.

Comment: I just discovered that the implicit isn't working in IE... .any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Both are correct, but putting the input inside the label makes it much less flexible when styling with CSS.

First, [a `<label>` is restricted in which elements it can contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). For example, you can only put a `<div>` between the `<input>` and the label text, if the `<input>` is not inside the `<label>`.

Second, while there are workarounds to make styling easier like wrapping the inner label text with a span, some styles will be in inherited from parent elements, which can make styling more complicated.

#### 3rd party edit

According to my understanding [html 5.2 spec for label](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-label-element) states that the labels  `Content model` is `Phrasing content`. This means only tags whose content model is phrasing content `<label> are allowed inside  </label>`.

> Content model A normative description of what content must be included
> as children and descendants of the element.
>
> Most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only
> contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content,
> not any flow content.

Comment: much less flexible?  can you elaborate?  as others have mentioned, you can simply wrap the inner label text with a span, unless that is what makes it much less flexible?

Comment: @nicholaides did you mean this reason why label can only contain certain other tags?

Comment: @surfmuggle yes

Answer (score 8):

A notable 'gotcha' dictates that you should never include more than one input element inside of a <label> element with an explicit "for" attribute, e.g:

```
<label for="child-input-1">
  <input type="radio" id="child-input-1"/>
  <span> Associate the following text with the selected radio button: </span>
  <input type="text" id="child-input-2"/>
</label>
```

While this may be tempting for form features in which a custom text value is secondary to a radio button or checkbox, the click-focus functionality of the label element will immediately throw focus to the element whose id is explicitly defined in its 'for' attribute, making it nearly impossible for the user to click into the contained text field to enter a value.

Personally, I try to avoid label elements with input children. It seems semantically improper for a label element to encompass more than the label itself. If you're nesting inputs in labels in order to achieve a certain aesthetic, you should be using CSS instead.

Comment: This isn't a "gotcha".  It's explicitly part of the spec; the label may contain up to 1 control in it.  You're also mixing the implicit and explicit styles here -- if you put the control inside the label, you don't need `for`...and if you want to use `for`, then having the control inside the label doesn't make much sense.

Comment: True, but it would seem that this specification isn't well-understood. We ran into this issue with Drupal 6's forms API, which generated markup that created a scenario not unlike that described above. It had my colleague and I scratching our heads for a minute or two, so I thought I'd air out the issue here to avert potential confusion in the future.

Comment: no need for "for" in label->input scenario. one input per label and it has the benefit of not having to know the name or id and you can do nice css styling to keep things encapsulated as well as having the focus occur when any other element such within is clicked. see zipstory.com/signup for example of clean way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you; this answered another related question I had, namely whether it goes to have potentially more than one input inside a label. (Context: Several radio button options, one per line, each radio button entry having 1, 2, 3, or possibly more inputs of type text, with the intent of clicking on a line having the result of selecting that line's radio button, if not selected, and allowing editing of the input/inputs on that line.) This leaves the door open to having multiple labels for non-input text in the form, but it answered my question about whether what I thought of was OK. (It wasn't.)

Answer (score 8):

As most people have said, both ways work indeed, but I think only the first one should. Being semantically strict, the label does not "contain" the input. In my opinion, containment (parent/child) relationship **in the markup structure** should reflect containment **in the visual output**. i.e., an element surrounding another one **in the markup** should be drawn around that one **in the browser**. According to this, the label should be the input's sibling, not it's parent. So option number two is arbitrary and confusing. Everyone that has read the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) will probably agree (Flat is better than nested, Sparse is better than dense, There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it...).

Because of decisions like that from W3C and major browser vendors (allowing "whichever way you prefer to do it", instead of "do it the right way") is that the web is so messed up today and we developers have to deal with tangled and so diverse legacy code.

Comment: The fundamental flaw of the first two options is that they require IDs, and are thus unsuitable for modular content. A form should, without knowledge of its surroundings, take care that it is repeatable on the page, and when using IDs, this means prefixing or other shenanigans, whereas nesting avoids this.

Answer (score 5):

I usually go with the first two options. I've seen a scenario when the third option was used, when radio choices where embedded in labels and the css contained something like

```
label input {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

in order to ensure proper vertical alignment for the radios.

Answer (score 4):

I greatly prefer to wrap elements inside my `<label>` because I don't have to generate the ids.

I am a Javascript developer, and React or Angular are used to generate components that can be reused by me or others. It would be then **easy to duplicate an id** in the page, leading there to strange behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the **WHATWG** ([Writing a form's user interface](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#writing-a-form%27s-user-interface)) it is not wrong to put the input field inside the label. This saves you code because the `for` attribute from the `label` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to consider is the interaction of checkbox and radio inputs with javascript.

Using below structure:

```
<label>
  <input onclick="controlCheckbox()" type="checkbox" checked="checkboxState" />
  <span>Label text</span>
</label>
```

When user clicks on "Label text" controlCheckbox() function will be fired once.

But when input tag is clicked the controlCheckbox() function may be fired twice in some older browsers. That's because both input and label tags trigger onclick event attached to checkbox.

Then you may have some bugs in your checkboxState.

I've run into this issue lately on IE11. I'm not sure if modern browsers have troubles with this structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several advantages of nesting the inputs into a label, especially with radio/checkbox fields,

```css
.unchecked, .checked{display:none;}
  label input:not(:checked) ~ .unchecked{display:inline;}
  label input:checked ~ .checked{display:inline;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="something" name="my_checkbox"/>
  <span class="unchecked">Not Checked</span>
  <span class="checked">Is Checked</span>
</label>
```

As you can see from the demo, nesting the input field first followed by other elements allows,

- The text to be clicked to activate the field
- The elements following the input field to be dynamically styled according to the status of the field.

In addition, HTML std allows [multiple labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_structure_a_web_form#multiple_labels) to be associated with an input field, however this will confuse screen readers and one way to get round this is to nest the input field and other elements within a single label element.

Comment: You can still do the same with unnested labels : https://jsfiddle.net/n4zc95s1/ 
And having a single label meaning 2 different thing like this proposal might be problematic to get an accessible form. For the sake of WCAG, I'd go split with this one.

Comment: true, but I still find one label for one input field is much cleaner to work with.  Nesting the input in the label also allows for pseudo elements to be inserted and doing more complex UIs such as [checkbox tree views](https://codepen.io/aurovrata/pen/VwPXreX).

Answer (score 0):

Although rare and avoidable, the combination of CSS selector and HTML may force you to use one form over the other. For example, a popular strategy to build a collapsible div using CSS requires a hidden checkbox to keep the collapse state and keeps an arrow in the label. The arrow rotation is implement using:

```
input:checked + label::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

There is no selector that would allow you to do this with the label around the input.