# Inline form fields with labels placed on top

Tags: html, css, forms

I can't believe I'm having to ask this, but I'm at my wit's end.

I'm trying to display 2 form fields inline, but with the label for each field on the top.  In ascii art:

```
Label 1      Label 2
---------    ---------
|       |    |       |
---------    ---------
```

Should be pretty simple.

```
<label for=foo>Label 1</label>
<input type=text name=foo id=foo />

<label for=bar>Label 2</label>
<input type=text name=bar id=bar />
```

This will get me:

```
        ---------           ---------
Label 1 |       |   Label 2 |       |
        ---------           ---------
```

To get the labels on top of the boxes, I add display=block:

```
<label for=foo style="display:block">Label 1</label>
<input type=text name=foo id=foo />

<label for=bar  style="display:block">Label 2</label>
<input type=text name=bar id=bar />
```

After I do this, the labels are where I want them, but the form fields are no longer inline:

```
Label 1  
---------
|       |
---------

Label 2  
---------
|       |
---------
```

I've been unable to find a way to wrap my html so the fields display inline. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would put each input inside an span with `display:inline-block`, like this:

```
<span style="display:inline-block">
    <label for=foo style="display:block">Label 1</label>
    <input type=text name=foo id=foo />
</span>

<span style="display:inline-block">
    <label for=bar  style="display:block">Label 2</label>
    <input type=text name=bar id=bar />
</span>
```

Comment: I like that you used span instead of div. Because then its also supported by IE 7.

Comment: How can I do the same using dForms?

Answer (score 19):

EDIT:

The original answer has not aged well since 2010. Placing inputs within labels used to be a common practice back then in order to avoid creating additional DOM elements for styling.

As web development for accessibility (a11y) compliance has matured since, (And as @CrandellWS points out in the comments below) the general consensus is that [@Raugturi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041615/inline-form-fields-with-labels-placed-on-top/3041658#answer-3041643) is more appropriate now.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You could enclose your inputs in with the labels and then use CSS:

```css
label{display:inline-block;}
input{display:block;}
```

```html
<label>Label 1<input type=text name=foo id=foo /></label>
<label>Label 2<input type=text name=bar id=bar /></label>
```

Comment: This works too. It was display:inline-block that was key to solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer thanks. I was looking for a generic solution that would let me display the labels on top *only* for some inputs. It doesn't make sense for checkbox or radios...

Comment: One might ask [Should I put input tag inside label tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/774054/1815624)