# Form horizontal layout with labels on top through css

Tags: jquery, css, forms, select, label

I'd like to have a form with several select controls in a horizontal (they are next to each other) layout and have labels on top of each select.

Like this:

[Inline form fields with labels placed on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041615/inline-form-fields-with-labels-placed-on-top)

How can I do that with css and using dform?

Comment: I don't know about `dform`, but what's wrong with the answer to the question to which you linked..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer using dform. Thank you for negative voting.

css for span... display:inline-block
label and select...  display : block

`$('#myform').dform({
            "action" : "dform.html",
            "method" : "get",
            "html" :
            [

    {
      "type": "span",
      "html": {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Country",
        "caption": "Country",
        "class": "countries",
        "options": {
          "": "All",
          "USA": {
            "html": "USA",
            "class": "active"
          },
          "Germany": {
            "html": "Germany",
            "class": "active"
          },
          "France": {
            "html": "France",
            "class": "active"
          }
        },
        "selected": null
      }
    } 
    ]
      });`

Comment: this is only one `select` type, I need to put one more `select` horizontally to first one; it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Best to just use an unordered list I think.

Float the LI elements to the left and give them some margin-right to space them.

You'll need a clearfixer element on the UL or it's parent to make sure the float works.

```
<ul>

<li><label>Label #1</label>
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</li>

<li><label>Label #1</label>
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</li>

<li><label>Label #1</label>
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</li>

</ul>
```