# Why aren't the labels of my checkboxes clickable on iPad?

Tags: html, forms, ipad, checkbox, html-input

Clicking the label of my checkboxes for the form below does not make the checkbox selected when using an iPad. I thought this should happen as the input is within the label. Thanks

```
    <fieldset>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep first-my"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" />Any</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />1</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />2</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />3</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />4</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />5</label>
        <label class="form-cont-my-sep"><input type="checkbox" />6</label>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: They are clickable, and they do toggle the checked state of the checkbox. What range of browsers did you test in? Do  you have other code on the page that could interfere?

Comment: Its an iPad issues, ive updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's an [iOS 4 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421659/html-label-command-doesnt-work-in-iphone-browser). Adding an empty `onclick` on the `fieldset` fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've given does infact work.

Another way of doing this is to create the association between the label and checkbox by id.

This is done by adding an `id` to the checkbox and referencing it in the `for` attribure on your label.

```
<label for="myCheckboxId">Foo</label><input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxId" />
```

[Here's a working sample of both methods](http://jsfiddle.net/DYY3S/).

Comment: You shouldn't need to that since the OP has the `input` as a child of the `label`, which works effectively in the same way as what you have (without the need for the `for` attribute).

Comment: Putting the checkbox inside the label element associates it without the need for a `for` attribute (except, IIRC, in some older versions of IE).

Comment: This is what ive read. I also tried adding the for and id, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the  in the  tag it should all work out of the box - you don't need a 'for' attribute to the  tag in this case:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />Any</label>
```

If you put the  outside the  then you do need a 'for' attribute to it:

```
<label for="myCheckBox">Any</label><input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
```

This is the HTML part of things, but I've seen a very strange issue with unclickable labels on a production server.

I don't know if this is your case, but here's what my "strange checkbox label mystery" was:
It had to do with CakePHP 1.3 and it's FormHelper. After some fiddling the issue turned out to be that CentOS's "perl compatible regular expressions" package was at a very old version. Upgrading to a newer one fixed it. I think the package name was "pcre...".

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well. In my case, the design was a custom checkbox/radio implementation which means the original checkbox/radio is hidden completely, leaving the user no avenue by which to alter their selection.

I also had the form element inside the label. Fieldset solution above did nothing. Binding the label to the form element using `for="<field-id>"` did not work either.

What did work was:

```
<label onclick="this.querySelector('input').click()">
    <input type="radio" />
</label>
```