# elements display incorrectly on tablet browsers

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, cross-browser

I'm currently working on one of my first two projects and you can tell that I'm still at the beginning of my youtube-tutorials-&-SO-powered learning journey:

[our neighbor's skin & beauty spa](http://www.izzas-skin-care.com)

Please don't be too harsh on my code :D I've hand-written everything from scratch in a little editor.

In short, everything seems to work A-OK on desktop computers (I tested FF and Chrome), but on the iPad and other tablets I'm experiencing nasty bugs - I'm having major trouble with two issues:

1. the Google Maps iframe is always visible (overlaps other
   sections) on tablets even if the corresponding section isn't clicked
   on in the menu, and I have no idea why! It seems that the
   visibility:hidden on a position-fixed element isn't interpreted
   correctly?
2. :focus works on the image gallery 'sneak peak', but
   in the services section, the 4 sub-content areas are inaccessible.
3. (Unrelated?) When the page loads on my iPad (mini) the #logo_box
   div appears at page load, but turns semi-transparent the very
   instant as the map iframe appears.

EFFORT1: I removed the Google maps iframe-containing 'content' container altogether, and suddenly the :hover on the other content sections stopped working as well. This might be an indicator that something is 'linked' in a way that's not right...

EFFORT2: I assumed that the  < label> is the culprit, but I can't pinpoint it. I tried [this suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421659/html-label-command-doesnt-work-in-iphone-browser), but it's for IOS4 (2011), and as Rob Fletcher commented last Feb., it doesn't work on IOS7.

EFFORT3: I feel that the .content div's {visibility:hidden/visible;} is causing trouble in the android mobile browser: input:checked *hides* instead of reveals the particular section while all others show.

Btw, how do I friggin' trouble-shoot tablets? I don't have any dev tool on ipad & android browsers.

Help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You can use Google Chrome dev tools and Emulation there to debug your code.

Comment: Well I'm always using Google dev tools but I didn't know that I can emulate things there! Will look into it and post an update if I find something cool there - Thanks!

Comment: In Google Chrome, hit `SHIFT+CTRL+J` then `ESC` then click `Emulation`

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Oh, in my mac version, shift+cmd+j brings up the downloads window. Shift+ctrl+j has no effect. I'll google!

Comment: I tried the emulator but in that mode, I couldn't replicate any of the bugs (will add screenshot of bugs to question).

Answer (score 1):

On iPad, you can go into the Settings App, then go Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector.

Then plug it into your Mac via USB and open Desktop Safari on the Mac. If you haven't already enabled the Develop menu, go Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop Menu.

Then when you open a web page in Safari on the iPad, you can connect to it via the Develop menu on your Mac's Safari and use the web inspector.

If you're using Chrome on Android you can use remote debugging https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

[Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Home.html) provides similar functionality across more platforms (including Android native browser), but is a bit more involved to set up.

Comment: Awesome! That's very helpful! I'm trying it out right now. Will give you a 'useful' as soon as I reach 15 rep :)

Comment: unfortunately I'll need an OSX upgrade first... :( can't connect to the ipad mini directly. But thanks for it anyways. Mental note...

Comment: @NilsSens Ouch, what version are you on? You can still use Weinre on the iPad, but as I said, it's a good bit more effort. Maybe not as much as an entire OS upgrade though.