# IE 8 and below not triggering click on elements which have display: none; Any workaround?

Tags: jquery, css, input, internet-explorer-8

> #### The issue is with Internet Explorer 8 and below. Have found a decent working solution.

#### Issue

Internet Explorer 8 and below is not triggering `click()` event set by jQuery (or even may be inline, not sure) on `<input />` elements, which have CSS property, `display` set to `none`. It works in Internet Explorer 9, Mozilla Firefox, and Google Chrome. Weird. This is how the code is and is there any work-around for Internet Explorer 8 and below?

#### Context

The `input` to be clicked is given a style `display: none;`. And the function is given in the `click` event of the `input`. Since the whole stuff is inside the `label`, it triggers the `click` event on the `input` when the `label` clicked. You can take this as some kind of pretty selector, hiding the `input`.

The `label` implicitly transfers the `click` event to the first `input` by default, and that is what I wanna use it here. I don't want the users to see the ugly `input` here. Expected browser behaviour, but not working.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="button" value="Button 1" />
            Hello! This is a list item #1.
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="button" value="Button 2" />
            Hello! This is a list item #2.
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="button" value="Button 3" />
            Hello! This is a list item #3.
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

#### The Exact CSS which caused the Issue

```
ul li,
ul li label {display: block; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;}
ul li label input {display: none;}
ul li {border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
ul li:hover {background-color: #eee;}​
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        alert("Hey you! " + $(this).attr("value"));
    });
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSYuP/

---

#### Update #1: Tried giving `for` attribute:

```
<label for="btn1">
    <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="btn1" />
```

Still doesn't work!

---

#### Update #2: Tried CSS `visibility: hidden;`:

```
ul li label input {visibility: hidden;}
```

Breaks layout. But, still doesn't work!

---

#### Update #3: Tried CSS `position: absolute;`:

```
ul li label {overflow: hidden;}
ul li label input {position: absolute; left: -99em;}
```

**Works!** I am not in a position to use `overflow: hidden;`, seriously caught!

---

#### Update #4: Manually triggering the `click()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        console.log("Hey you! " + $(this).attr("value"));
    });
    $("label").click(function(){
        $(this).find("input").click();
    });
});
```

Well, IE 8 goes out of stack after printing `LOG: Hey you! Button 3` for **1209** times!

```
LOG: Hey you! Button 3 
LOG: Hey you! Button 3 
LOG: Hey you! Button 3 
LOG: Hey you! Button 3 
LOG: Hey you! Button 3 
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
```

**Works Infinitely!** Should be an issue with my script!

---

#### Solution: Kind of crappy fix, but did the trick!

Since it is because IE 8, which supports `opacity`, I had to use `display: inline-block;` with `opacity: 0;`.

```
ul li label input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Now the `input`'s box is hidden, literally. This fix is only for IE 8!

Had to fix using the **IE 8 and below Hack**:

```
ul li label input {
    opacity: 0\9;
    width: 0px\9;
    height: 0px\9;
    display: inline-block\9;
    padding: 0\9;
    margin: 0\9;
    border: 0\9;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VSQbD/

Comment: why would you expect a click handler to work on something that cannot be clicked on?

Comment: @ahren The input to be clicked is hidden. And the function gets triggered on the click of the `input`. Since the whole stuff is inside the `label`, it triggers the `click` event on the `input` when it is clicked. Some kinda pretty selector, you see?

Comment: Why don't you just bind the handler to the `li`? Also, it's probably something to do with the fact IE doesn't recognise nested inputs to be associated with parent labels... maybe if you use the `for` attribute it might work... but this is just me guessing.

Comment: Tried giving `for` attribute:

    `<label for="btn1">
        <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="btn1" />`

Still doesn't work!

Comment: have you tried triggering it directly? so by calling `$('input').click()` on some other procedure and if yes what were the results?

Comment: @Vogel612 Triggering the `input` via javascript injection? Haven't done that. Will try and get back to you!

Comment: @Vogel612 Your suggestion, my stupid script made IE 8 going out of stack after printing `LOG: Hey you! Button 3` for **1209** times!

Comment: Use focusin instead click. It'll work every where in any condition.

Comment: make it browser specific : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Comment: @BerkerYüceer Not good to sniff browser using JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is pretty straightforward.  You just have to use click handlers on visible items.  If you want a click on the `<label>` or the `<li>` to work when the `<input>` object is hidden and you want it to work in all browsers, then you just need to put a click handler on either the `<label>` or the `<li>` because that is a visible object that will receive the click when the `<input>` is hidden.

Comment: The `label` implicitly transfers the `click` event to the first `input` by default, and that is what I wanna use it here. I don't want the users to see the ugly `input` here. Expected browser behaviour, but not working. The thing is, it works in all the standard browsers!

Comment: *Expected browser behaviour* isn't something that really exists in web development...

Comment: @PraveenKumar - are you expecting some magic incantation that will give features to IE8 that it doesn't have.  The work-around is to attach a click handler to a visible object.  You can keep the `<input>` item hidden, but you need a click handler on a visible item if you want code to act on the click.

Comment: The idea is to trigger the click event on the `input`. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar - guess what!  IE8 doesn't do give the click event to the hidden `<input>` item so stop asking for it to do that - it doesn't.  You need to code around that by having a click handler on a visible item and then triggering the same code that you have for click handlers on the `<input>` item.  This is how you solve interoperability issues in older browsers.

Comment: `+1` Grrr.. Stupid IE! I know... No other way?

Comment: @ahren - love your comment about "expected browser behavior"!

Comment: @ahren Yeah, me too. Nice explanation. Web developers enter hell when trying for cross browser compatibility. `:(`

Comment: @jfriend00 Consider this. Having a `form` submission with the value of the `input type="radio"`, and I need something like pretty forms. That time, what I do is, I just use a toggle class of `selected` and when selected is there, an inline hidden tick image is shown inline. Got my point?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I have no idea what your last comment means.

Comment: Anyways, added `+1` for your explanation. Will explain you in detail in a fiddle. Give me some time. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

#### Kind of crappy fix, but did the trick!

Since it is because IE 8, which supports `opacity`, I had to use `display: inline-block;` with `opacity: 0;`.

```
ul li label input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Now the `input`'s box is hidden, literally. This fix is only for IE 8!

Tried using the IE 8 Hack:

```
ul li label input {
    opacity: 0\9;
    width: 0px\9;
    height: 0px\9;
    display: inline-block\9;
    padding: 0\9;
    margin: 0\9;
    border: 0\9;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, found the issue, targetted it, fixed it! :) BTW, what did you change in the fiddle?

Comment: i just changed the js code made the label clickable and found the inputs value under it.

Comment: Ah saw that. Dude, the problem is, consider a *pretty* form, where when you add a class to the `label`, it displays a cute tick image. In that case, you need to trigger the `input` to set the value to submit the form. Got it?

Comment: you can also do it the other way by adding click event on parents of inputs such as : http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/VSQbD/2/

Comment: You can't. The click event should be on the `input`.

Comment: i guess ur having a huge mistake here! cause you dont need to implement class or anything.. u only use dom spesific elements as `.parent('label')` and adding `.click()` event to it. This will not cause anything look with a cute tick image. So it behaves like input click event actually.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not position the element absolute, but set it's left property to something like -99999px?

Comment: It's a crappy fix. Keeping it as the last option.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "for" attribute on the labels and an id on the inputs?

Comment: Check the Update #1 in the question. It didn't work! See, am saying it only for IE 8 and below. IE 9 handles perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

different browsers interpret  `display:none` differently. `display:none` actually means the element should disappear, making the jquery difficult to find in the DOM.

a better way is to use `visibility:hidden` and then use `click` method

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much incorrect..

- `input` inside `label` ?
- Events are suppose to bubble up and not downwards
- and its so simple.. if you want to know when li was clicked attach an handler to that and not to input

in your updated 4 you could do an `event.stopPropagation` for 'input` click and that would solve infinity problem

Comment: Ah, thanks for the solution of solving the infinity thing. `input` inside the `label` is **the** right way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag :)

Comment: though valid just doesn't sound right to most of the people even at that page. Didn't know its valid . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never been hit by this as I do things slightly differently anyway - click on the label does `input.checked = !input.checked; return false;`, then have a "change" event on the input (rather than a click event).