# Radio button not working as I wish

Tags: css, radio-button

For my project, I have a series of radio buttons. This is going to work like a rating system, where they choose a rating on a place.

```
<div class="float-left">
  <label><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="1" />1</label>
</div>   
<div class="float-left">
  <label><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="2" />2</label>
</div>   
<div class="float-left">
  <label><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="3" />3</label>
</div>   
<div class="float-left">
  <label><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="4" />4</label>
</div>   
<div class="float-left">
  <label><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="5" />5</label>
</div>
```

What is produced seems very strange to me The numbers and buttons are very far from each other.

[image: Radio Button Rating System]

Comment: You need to post some CSS or a working example on jsFiddle. I don't think there is enough information to get an answer at the moment.

Comment: The numbers and buttons are very far from each other...That is what I am complaaining about

Comment: Just try to trace styles in your browser

Comment: Take the input out of the label for each, see below

Comment: We need to see your CSS to answer this correctly.

On your code: keep in mind that each ID can be used only once per page (the code is using it five times now).
Inputs should be **outside** of labels. If you wish to make the label clickable, read up on the label's "for" attribute.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is giving me those Ids. I use Html helpers...
But the error keeps coming even if I use  Html with no helpers

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes labels *may* be near the inputs or around the inputs.

Comment: @hazzik placing inputs inside labels create issues with certain screen readers. Well, more discussion there -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have width style for *all* `input` tags. Try to reset it for `input[type="radio"]`:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    width: initial;
}
```

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/Pgcmv/4/

After: http://jsfiddle.net/Pgcmv/2/

**UPD**: In this case initial works only in Chrome 26, Firefox 16 and Safari 5 and does not work in Opera 12 and IE 10. So you need to set some small value that will appropriate in your case.

Comment: Widht: initial didnt work... but widht:30px worked...
thx for the help

Comment: Yes, initial may depend on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the labels to float left and the inputs to float left, then took the inputs outside of the labels to fix it:

My HTML:

```
<div class ="float-left "><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="1" /><label> 1</label></div>   
<div class ="float-left "><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="2" /> <label> 2</label></div>   
<div class ="float-left "><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="3" /><label> 3</label> </div>   
<div class ="float-left "><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="4" /><label> 4</label> </div>   
<div class ="float-left "><input id="Rating" name="Rating" type="radio" value="5" /><label> 5</label> </div>
```

Comment: Then labels will not be clickable

Comment: I would recommend making them clickable in a different way. The question about the validity of this practice was raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag and although either way is valid, my approach will give you the style control that you are looking for.

Comment: Don't you just need to decrease the width of your inputs?