# Best format for the form label tag

Tags: html, label

Out of the following 2, which is the better syntax and why?

```
<label for="textfield1">Hello</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1" />
```

or

```
<label>Hello2
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" />
</label>
```

Comment: Depends on the styles you apply

Comment: Probably best ask that here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag

Comment: There the same, on the **HTML** part.

Comment: I recommend you first one. For me, have no sense to introduce an input into a label.

Comment: I prefer second one because you put input inside label and input is strictly related to label. Another reason is that it's easier for styling for me. btw. in second example label should also have for="id-of-your-input".

Comment: Actually have I got the first one wrong. Should the for= be linked to an ID and not a name?

Comment: @user1001421 yes, id not name

Comment: Edit your post, to avoid confusion with the id and name parameter. Aside from this both of them are valid and perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok. The lack of the id aside, I'm guessing it really doesn't matter. Both seem to be valid syntax and it's just down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Better* is somewhat subjective. There are various things you could measure, but you have to determine which you care about the most.

These are the facts. Using a `for` attribute:

- has better support in Old-IE
- requires more code
- gives different options for what you can do with CSS (in particular, using a `for` attribute allows the elements to be separated).

Comment: Thank you. You kind of confirmed what I suspected. Just wanted to see if one syntax had any merits over the other one. Thanks for your response.