# how to get text associated in a html input tag of type checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have my element like below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Countries" value="Ind">India</input>
```

How to get output as "India"?
Below returns only Ind

```
document.getElementById("Countries").value;
```

Comment: `input` is a self-closing tag.

Comment: _Tag omission: Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag._ [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: Dont forget to mark the right answer if there was one for you1

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to get the value when you don't care about semantically correctness.

```js
alert(document.getElementById('Countries').nextSibling.nodeValue);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Countries" value="Ind">India</input>
```

For completeness:

You shoult do an input type like this as mentioned in the [Form W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)

```
<label for="Countrie">India</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Countrie" />
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Countrie" />
<label for="Countrie">India</label>
```

or

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Countrie" />
   India
</label>
```

also mentioned in [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774065/2667584)
and then use javaScript to get a coresponding `label` value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because your `html` is wrong.

`input` is a self closing tag, so it should be like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Countries" value="Ind" />
```

So there is no other value you could extract with javascript then the `value`.
Or you should use a `data-attribute` with India as a value.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-country="India" id="Countries" value="Ind" />
```

JS

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#Countries'); // or document.getElementById("Countries");

alert(checkbox.dataset.country);
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zwx43m59/

Comment: it is possible as you can see in my post

Comment: @StevenWeb Yes, you're right, but your html isn't valid. Or it is XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can because that isn't valid HTML code.

An input tag is empty, meaning that it can only contain attributes. Therefore, there is no `</input>` to close it.

There are ways to store data in it though.

As of HTML 5, there is a data- attribute that you can put on any element. You could do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Countries" value="Ind" data-something="India" />

// Inside JS
document.querySelector("#Countries").dataset.something
```

Another alternative would be to wrap a p or a span around the text after it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Countries" value="Ind" />
<p id="CountriesText">You can get this value easily enough</p>
```