# HTML5 "label" element, nested or "for"?

Tags: html, input, label

Are there reasons to prefer using the HTML5 element "label"

1. to wrap the "input" element
2. with a "for" attribute

i.e. to prefer

```
<label><input></label>
```

to

```
<label for="inp"></label><input id="inp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a reason for this.

> The  element does not render as anything special for the user.
>   However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because
>   if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles
>   the control.

when you include `<label for="#yourControlID"><input id="yourControlID"></label>` it will attach with that particular input control. For example look at the below snippet.

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <label>Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Try clicking on `label - Male`. The toggle doesn't happen but if you click on `label-female` it toggles.

So basically what it does is, when you try to remove `for` from label it will stop binding that particular label to the control and when you click on the label without `for` in it, it will not actually toggle the radio element.

**[SOURCE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was about choosing the best way to link a label to an input.  One option is to nest the `<input>` inside.  Another is to have the elements as peers and use the `for` and `id` attributes.  Which is best?

Comment: I think **[this liink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag)** will give you more clear answer. Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks I just found that too and have already voted to close my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh.. Its ok.. Happy coding.. :)