# How to modify label of input using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like following :

```
<div class="task-manager">
    <label>Manager: <input type="text" value="" /></label>
</div>
```

I need to modify text of label Manager dynamically. 
I tried using JQUERY text method, but it replaces input type also.

```
$taskTemplate.find(".task-manager label").text("M123")
```

Comment: thats because your input tag is inside your label tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$taskTemplate.find(".task-manager label").contents().get(0).nodeValue = "M123:";
```

Comment: Never knew that was possible , but its not easy to understand for beginners :/

Answer (score 1):

You should change your HTML code, because `<input>` field is inside `<label>` and when you are changing value of this label, it's also overwriting and removing input form field:

```
<div class="task-manager">
    <label>Manager:</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it not possible without changing HTML. I am able to get value using $taskTemplate.find(".task-manager label").contents().get(0).nodeValue, but can not modify it. thanks for help

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes why, because it is valid to get input wrapped inside label

Comment: @vinodsahu  $taskTemplate.find(".task-manager label").contents().get(0).nodeValue = "M123:" would set it

Comment: @A.Wolff sure, [you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/774054/1267304). I thought it was against the patterns.

Comment: But the label won't work properly this way. The `label` needs a `for` attribute with the `input`'s id.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the Input tag outside the `label` tag, because when your updating the text of your label, its erasing the content of label (which will obviously remove input tag `inside` it) , so change your code like this

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="task-manager">
   <label for="title">Manager:</label>
   <input type="text" id = 'title' value="" />
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
    $('.task-manager label').text('Deputy Manager :');
```

Live Demo @ Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/w6arp71x/

*note/suggestion:`for` attribute added to label to bind the `input` to the `label` by default*

Comment: This doesn't work. The `label` needs a `for` attribute with the `input`'s id.

Comment: @Perplexor: your suggestion will obviously make it a better code, but OP never had this before either. anyway suggestion taken :)

Comment: But this suggestion changes other behaviours on the site. You can't just assume that OP is okay with that while it indeed will resolve his initial issue.

Comment: @Perplexor: The First Rule on SO is not to intervene with OP's code which would change the entire behaviour, obviously any good notes can be suggested which could improve the code

Comment: And that's exactly why I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$taskTemplate.find(".task-manager label").contents().get(0).nodeValue = "M123:"
```

this worked for :)