# inserting php code inside EOT

Tags: php, html, mysql

There are two tables, products and productcolor. Each product can have multiple color. I want to fetch color of products in dropdown. But not able to do that with following code.

```
 <?php
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
    if($results){ 
    $products_item = '<ul class="products">';
    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {  
        $id = $obj->id;
        $results1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT colornmae FROM productcolor where id=$id");
      if($results1){ 
        while($obj1 = $results1->fetch_object())
        {  
        $color[] = $obj1->colorname;
        }
      }
    $products_item .= <<<EOT
        <li class="product">
        <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
        <div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
        <div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/{$obj->product_img_name}"></div>
        <div class="product-desc">{$obj->product_desc}</div>
        <div class="product-info">
        Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

        <fieldset>

        <label>
            <span>Color</span>
            <select name="product_color">
            foreach ($color as $value) {
            <option value="{$value}">{$value}</option>
            }
            </select>
        </label>

        <label>
            <span>Quantity</span>
            <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
        </label>

        </fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
        <div align="center"><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button></div>
        </div></div>
        </form>
        </li>
    EOT;
    }
    $products_item .= '</ul>';
    echo $products_item;
    }
    ?>
```

I have searched for solution. Then I came to know that php code can't be written in `EOT`. *php variables can be shown in EOT. But here i want to do looping to values of color from database.* I have tried various combination but nothing worked. Above is my one of the attempt of doing that which is not working.

How do I get `colorname` of product in dropdown which is fetching from database as object in between `EOT`?

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/The-Basics.html

Comment: @N000b101: how do i show looping for color values fetched from database in EOT?

Comment: according to this, http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?263544-Simplest-method-to-loop-inside-heredoc-syntax it's NOT possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you :

- do not have **ANY** other characters (including whitespace characters) on the same line as your `EOT;` statement.
- do not have any PHP expressions in your string. Only variables are allowed and they **MUST** have the format `{$variable}`.

To make your code more readable, you should also fix your indentation!

---

This code should work:

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
    $products_item = '<ul class="products">';
    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {  
        $id = $obj->id;
        $results1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT colorname FROM productcolor where id=$id");
        $color = array();
        if($results1){ 
            while($colorvalue = $results1->fetch_object()) {  
                $color[] = $colorvalue->colorname;
            }
        }
        $products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
        <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <img src="images/{$obj->product_img_name}">
                </div>
                <div class="product-desc">
                    {$obj->product_desc}
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

                    <fieldset> 
                        <label>
                            <span>Color</span>
                            <select name="product_color">
EOT;
        foreach ($color as $value) {
        $products_item .= <<<EOT
                                <option value="{$value}">{$value}</option>
EOT;
        }
        $products_item .= <<<EOT
                            </select>
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span>Quantity</span>
                            <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
                        </label>

                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
                    <div align="center">
                        <button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
EOT;
    }
    $products_item .= '</ul>';
    echo $products_item;
}
?>
```

---

As an alternative to splitting your string into bits, you could put your expressions in a seperate function/method and include its output as a variable.

This code should also work:

```
<?php
function print_colors($color) {
    $returnstring = "";
    foreach ($color as $value) {
        $returnstring .= "<option value=\"{$value}\">{$value}</option>";
    }
    return $returnstring;
}

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
    $products_item = '<ul class="products">';
    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {  
        $id = $obj->id;
        $results1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT colorname FROM productcolor where id=$id");
        $color = array();
        if($results1){ 
            while($colorvalue = $results1->fetch_object()) {  
                $color[] = $colorvalue->colorname;
            }
        }
        $products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
        <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <img src="images/{$obj->product_img_name}">
                </div>
                <div class="product-desc">
                    {$obj->product_desc}
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

                    <fieldset> 
                        <label>
                            <span>Color</span>
                            <select name="product_color">
                                {print_colors($color)}
                            </select>
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span>Quantity</span>
                            <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
                        </label>

                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
                    <div align="center">
                        <button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
EOT;
    }
    $products_item .= '</ul>';
    echo $products_item;
}
?>
```

Comment: @ John Slegers: the values of color is not displaying. is my code of fetching color values is right?

Comment: @kiran : What IS showing? Do you get ANY output at all for your colors?

Comment: @kiran : You misspelled `colorname` in your SQL query. You spelled it as `colornmae` instead. I corrected the spelling in my code examples. Let me know if you still have a problem after fixing the spelling!

Comment: in above code `$color = [];` is this declaration right? getting syntax error here.

Comment: @kiran : What version of PHP are you using? If you're using PHP 5.3 or below, you should use `$color = array();` instead.

Comment: @kiran : I just updated my answer and replaced `$color = [];` with `$color = array();`, so it also works in PHP 5.3 and below.

Comment: @ John Slegers  : Thanks a lot for looking this again. I am using PHP 5.3.8 version. Still that was giving error. I replaced it with `$color = array();`. Its working now. :)

Answer (score 3):

When You use HEREDOC (it doesn't need to be 'EOT' it can be 'MYKEYWORD' as well), **ending point of HEREDOC, closing HEREDOC, must be first in the line, with no whitespace before, followed by the semicolon and nothing else after in that line**, otherwise it fails. That's why Your code won't work.

```
$heredoc = <<<KEYWORD

  {$variable} - this will print value of $variable 
  $variable - this will print $variable, not $variable value

KEYWORD;
```

EDIT:

I have noticed that You have foreach loop (pasted, just like that?) somewhere in between HEREDOC.

It won't work that way.

Write new method for html select > option -> value, outside that block of code, than call it, assign it to object property or variable, than use it within HEREDOC.. concatenate, whatever.

```
// New small method
public function smallLoop($color) {
    $x=null;
    foreach($color as $value)
    $x.='<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    return $x;
}

// Inside loop
<select name="product_color">
    {$obj->smallLoop($color)}
</select>
```

**NOTE**:

Your html semantic is also - bad. You probably don't want to wrap `<select> <option>` tags with `<label>`, also, Are You quite sure that You need `<form>` tag for each and every cart entry?!? No, no You don't.

You need only ONE form tag, I can bet..

My suggestion for You is to make Your self a cup of coffee, snap Your fingers, than re-write that whole block of code, again. Make it good. You can do it.

Comment: @ Spooky: I am not getting where i am making mistake. what should i change? Can you please explain with my code? How it should be?

Comment: His first opening `<?php` tag is not in the same indentation as the rest of the code.. that's why I wrote what I wrote.

Comment: @ Spooky : I am getting error in your `New small method` code. is there anything missing in that code?

Comment: @ kiran Sorry, I made a mistake with singlequote concat, I have edited that. It should be good now, however, take a look at NOTE part I aded.

Comment: @ kiran .. and if You read that NOTE, know that `label` requires `for` attribute, something like this `<label for="uniqueID"> Label text </label> <select id="uniqueID" name="uniqueID"><!-- option  value, option  value , option  value  .. --> </select>` ... That would be the proper HTML syntax/semantics.

Comment: @Spooky: Actually, a label is allowed to wrap a form element. And in that case, you do not nead to include a "for" property. This syntax is not commonly known, but it is valid. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag/774065#774065.

Comment: @ John Slegers .. Yes, it appears so it can be done, but I doubt that kiran will have benefits out of third valid example You pointed out.