# button not appearing after label?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give label after button,but the button is not appearing.
Is is working in fiddle but not in my local code.

Please solve the issue.

```html
<div style="float:left;padding-top:5px;">
  <span class="newrdb">
     <label for="all" style="padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:8px;width:100px;font-size:12px;float:left"> 
                                    Default Template
     <input type="radio" name="Template" id="all" value="Default Template" checked="">  
     </label>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: No No My requirement is to have a input field but i want the button to appear after the text

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs according to w3 it's fine. "_To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element_" https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL . See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tags-inside-a-label-tag

Comment: @ADyson ah I see, never ever seen it done, seems, well to me, illogical, but that's just me :) I'll remove my comment

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yeah I think it's a bit odd too and tend not to do it, but it's perfectly valid markup according to the spec.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @ADyson ok good good, not just me that finds it odd ahaha :)

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution.. Remove the `width:100px;`from the `label` *or give it more pixels...* 
The problem is, that **both** elements (the **text** and the **radio button**) don't fit together inside a `100px` element.. So by deleting it **or** making it wider, they will fit together.

```html
<div style="float:left;padding-top:5px;">
     <span class="newrdb">
          <label for="all" style="padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:8px;font-size:12px;float:left"> 
               Default Template
               <input type="radio" name="Template" id="all" value="Default Template" checked="">  
          </label>
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep input field outside of the label tag,

Try following code,

```html
<div style="float:left;padding-top:5px;">
  <span class="newrdb">
    <label for="all" style="padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:8px;font-size:12px;float:left;"> 
 Default Template
    </label>
     <input type="radio" name="Template" id="all" value="Default Template" checked="">  

 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: never just leave code - always add an explanation :)

Comment: Cool removing downvote :) though I will say, take a look at the comments on the OP's question - I too thought it was invalid markup but thanks to @ADyson - it turns out it's perfectly valid, just maybe not the best practice

Comment: Sucks right?! haha sorry to be the bearer of bad news :)