# Javascript event listener fires twice when clicking on text inside label element

Tags: javascript, label, addeventlistener

How do i make a function not fire twice when clicking on text inside a label.

If I use `event.preventDefault()` then basic browser functionality for making the checkbox checked will stop working too.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('.parent');

label.addEventListener('click', handleLabelClick);

function handleLabelClick(event) {
  console.log('Clicked')
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="option1">
    <span>Select me</span>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, you want clicks on `.parent` elements to fire a click handler, but you don't want that handler fired for clicks related to a checkbox or its label within `.parent`.

Two ways to do that:

1. Add a handler for the `label` that calls `stopPropagation`, or
2. Check within the event handler whether the event passed through the `label`

Here's approach #1:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', handleLabelClick);

// Stop clicks in the label or checkbox from propagating to parent
parent.querySelector("label").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

function handleLabelClick(event) {
 console.log('Clicked');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="option1">
    <span>Select me</span>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

Here's approach #2:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', handleLabelClick);

function handleLabelClick(event) {
  const label = event.target.closest("label");
  if (label && this.contains(label)) {
    // Ignore this click
    return;
  }
 console.log('Clicked');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="option1">
    <span>Select me</span>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @KlaudioMilankovic - I'm afraid I don't understand what you're describing.

Comment: So, lets say

<label for="option1" class="test">
    <span>Select me</span>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
  </label>

is a component on it's own and you place this inside other component named 'parent'. 

Once you attach event listener to a parent and click on a label it fires twice instead of once. 

I am trying NOT to handle clicks on label as this is done by the browser.

Comment: @KlaudioMilankovic - I think I understand. So in your example, you want the `handleLabelClick` to fire for clicks unrelated to the checkbox, and not for clicks related to the checkbox?

Comment: Exactly. 

I want to retain default browser functionality for checkboxes but not have it fire my function twice which is attached to a parent.

Comment: @KlaudioMilankovic - Good deal. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Option 1 was the solution for my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard (unfortunate) browser behavior.

Attribute `for` assigns `<label>` to `<input>`, so when `<label>` element is clicked, browser will emulate a click on `<input>` element right after your real click.

On a plus side, this allows focus of `<input type="text"`, switching of `<input type="radio"`, or toggling of `<input type="checkbox"`.
But for the unfortunate side, this also causes that **both elements send the *click* event**. In case you are listening on clicks on a parent element, this means that you'll receive one "human interaction" twice. Once from `<input>` and once from "the clicked element".

For those who wonder, [`<input>` could be inside `<label>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-elements-inside-a-label-element) element, you'll get less styling possibility, but you can then click in between check-box and text.

Your putting `<span>` and `<input>` inside `<label>` actually creates a nice test case.
Try clicking from left to right;
On the text, you'll receive SPAN + INPUT events,
between text and check-box you'll get LABEL + INPUT events,
on the check-box directly only INPUT event,
then further right, only DIV event.
(because DIV is a block element and spans all the way to the right)

One solution would be to listen only on `<input>` element events, but then you will not capture `<div>` clicks and you also can't put `<div>` inside `<label>`.

The simplest thing to do is to ignore clicks on `<label>` and all clickable elements inside `<label>` except `<input>`. In this case `<span>`.

```js
const elWrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

elWrapper.addEventListener('click', handleLabelClick);

function handleLabelClick(event) {
 console.log('Event received from tagName: '+event.target.tagName);
 if (event.target.tagName === 'LABEL' || event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') { return; }
 console.log('Performing some action only once. Triggered by click on: '+event.target.tagName);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="option1">
    <span>Select me</span>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

(from OP's example I changed **parent** to **wrapper** and **label** to **elWrapper**,
because **parent** and **label** are keywords.)

The solution from @T.J. causes events from `<label>` and everything inside it to be ignored down-the-road.
To get the event fired, you'd need to click somewhere on the `<div>`, but not directly on the text or check-box.

I added my answer because I didn't think this was the OP's intention.

But even for this other case, you might use similar approach as I offered above. Checking if clicked element name is DIV then allowing further actions. I think it's more straightforward, more localized (doesn't affect event propagation), more universal (if you select capturing: addEventListener(...,...,true) this will still work)

Comment: Thank you @papo! I just asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59252625/1795402) that actually started as observing this behavior. Your explanation of the 'why' clarifies things for me.