# When a `label` element contains a child `span`, clicking the label triggers on the child but not the parent

Tags: javascript, html

In this example, I've created a label group with a header, and have attempted to attach a click listener to each label; I eventually want an `input` inside each `label`, but it is not necessary to illustrate the behavior I don't understand.

I am seeing different behavior depending on whether I wrap the label text in a `span` tag:

- When the label **without** a child `span` is clicked, the event handler is called once as I would expect, on the `label` element.
- When the label **with** a child a `span` is clicked, the event handler is still called only once, but this time for the child `span` **and not for the parent `label`.**

I would have expected, in the second scenario, the event handler to trigger twice: once for the parent `label`, and once for the child `span`. Can someone explain why the addition of this `span` element seems to be preventing the event handler from propagating to the parent `label`?

```js
var settingsGroup = document.getElementById("settings");
settingsGroup.querySelectorAll('.setting').forEach(function(setting) {
  var options = setting.querySelectorAll('label');

  options.forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      console.log(`${this.id} clicked: ${ev.target.tagName}`);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="settings">
  <div class="setting" role="group">
    <div id="header">
      <em>
        A setting
      </em>
    </div>

    <label id="option-a">
      Option A
    </label>

    <label id="option-b">
      <span>
        Option B
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're adding the event handler to the `<label>`, so if the handler fires then it clearly is firing on the `<label>` element. The "target" of an event is always the specific DOM element involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. `e.target` is the element that was the target of the event (the `span` in the case of `<label><span>...</span></label>`. The *target* of the event is the `span`, and then the event propagates (bubbles) to its parent `label`, where it gets handled by your event handler.

If you want to look at the `label` instead, either use `this` as you have for `id`, or use `e.currentTarget` (the element the event is currently being delivered to).

This diagram from the old [DOM3 Events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) is handy for understanding event flow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The last part of the comment left by @Pointy helped me realize my expectations about how events are handled were flawed, and I found this exact bit of documentation at the same time as you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pointer-events" CSS directive to stop span HTML elements receiving mouse events.

```
span
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Good to know! I'm not looking for that behavior at the moment, but knowing it can be done through CSS will come in handy some day, I'm sure.