# Can't toggle checkbox through its label when `loop` is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

When I make my carousel with the `loop` option set to `true` it's impossible to toggle a checkbox clicking on the label associated with it.

Here's an example with both situations:

```js
let $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');

$carousel.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
});

document
  .querySelector('#btnReloadWithoutLoop')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    $carousel.data('owl.carousel').options.loop = false;
    $carousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });

document
  .querySelector('#btnReloadWithLoop')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    $carousel.data('owl.carousel').options.loop = true;
    $carousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.owl-carousel .item label {
  transition: text-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.owl-carousel .item input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-group>button+button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox">
      <label for="test-checkbox">Test label</label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox-2">
      <label for="test-checkbox-2">Test label</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btnReloadWithoutLoop">
    Reload WITHOUT the loop option
  </button>
  <button id="btnReloadWithLoop">
    Reload WITH the loop option
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click event listener to the `document.body` shows that clicking on the label registers **two click events**. It seems as though the carousel plugin may be firing a click event on the checkbox also, using the `for` attribute of the label, causing an immediate `checked="checked"` to `checked="false"` state.

You can work around this by adding the `input` inside the `label` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-elements-inside-a-label-element), and removing the label's `for` attribute. The plugin doesn't appear to trigger a "double" click event when doing so.

**Short Answer**

*Change:*

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox">
    <label for="test-checkbox">Test label</label>
</form>
```

*To:*

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox-2">
        Test label
    </label>
</form>
```

**Full Answer:**

```js
let $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');

$carousel.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
});

document
  .querySelector('#btnReloadWithoutLoop')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    $carousel.data('owl.carousel').options.loop = false;
    $carousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });

document
  .querySelector('#btnReloadWithLoop')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    $carousel.data('owl.carousel').options.loop = true;
    $carousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.owl-carousel .item label {
  transition: text-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.owl-carousel .item input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-group>button+button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <form>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox">
        Test label
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <form>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test-checkbox-2">
        Test label
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btnReloadWithoutLoop">
    Reload WITHOUT the loop option
  </button>
  <button id="btnReloadWithLoop">
    Reload WITH the loop option
  </button>
</div>
```