# Get radio button label to stay the same color once I've checked it

Tags: html, css

I have a radio where the options change from grey to black when the user hovers over them. But I want the checked option to remain black, even after the user is no longer hovering over it. I can't get it to do this at all.

```css
label {
  color: grey;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div star-buttons>
  <label><input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> ☆ <br></label>
  <label><input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <label><input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <label><input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="4"> ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <label><input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="5"> ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
</div>
```

I was trying to do something like in the last line of my CSS, but that's not working. How do I get this done?

Comment: `imput:checked + label` will match `<input><label></label>` and not  `<label><input></label>` There is no parent's selector :(

Comment: `star-buttons` is an invalid HTML5 attribute. Use `data-star-button` instead or whatever you were trying to... Class or ID perhaps?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think that was just a stupid mistake on my part. I meant to say class="star-buttons". Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

`+` is a sibling selector and with this markup the label is a parent. There is no parent selector in CSS. However we can still get this done! Place a wrapper around the stars to leverage the sibling selector like so:

```css
label {
  color: grey;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .stars-txt {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
    <div class="stars-txt">☆</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
    <div class="stars-txt">☆ ☆</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="3">
    <div class="stars-txt">☆ ☆ ☆</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="4">
    <div class="stars-txt">☆ ☆ ☆ ☆</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="5">
    <div class="stars-txt">☆ ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should set your input outside and before label so the selector `input[type="radio"]:checked+label`  will match your HTML

> **as commented earlier** `imput:checked + label` will match `<input><label></label>` and not `<label><input></label>` **There is no parent's selector** :(

See :

> Is there a best practice concerning the nesting of label and input HTML elements? [Should I put input elements inside a label element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-elements-inside-a-label-element)

and

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label
>
> The HTML  element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.
>
> Associating a  with an  element offers some major advantages:
>
> The label text is not only visually associated with its corresponding text input; it is programmatically associated with it too. This means that, for example, a screenreader will read out the label when the user is focused on the form input, making it easier for an assistive technology user to understand what data should be entered.
>
> You can click the associated label to focus/activate the input, as well as the input itself. This increased hit area provides an advantage to anyone trying to activate the input, including those using a touch-screen device.

update possible of your HTML

```css
label {
  color: grey;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div star-buttons>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" id="a"><label for="a"> ☆ <br></label>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="b"><label for="b"> ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="3" id="c"><label for="c"> ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="4"id ="d"><label for="d"> ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="5" id="e"><label for="e"> ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆<br></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your star characters inside a `<span>` like so:

```
<label>
     <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
     <span>☆</span>
</label>
```

Then in your CSS, change this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: black;
}
```

To this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed

Comment: If you find this helpful, an upvote would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you want to see those stars filled with color this is how I would do it:
Instead of using the stars in HTML I'm using the stars in CSS and I'm changing between `\02729` (empty star) and `\0272d` (filled star).

```css
label:nth-of-type(1)::before{content:'\02729'}
label:nth-of-type(2)::before{content:'\02729\02729'}
label:nth-of-type(3)::before{content:'\02729\02729\02729'}
label:nth-of-type(4)::before{content:'\02729\02729\02729\02729'}
label:nth-of-type(5)::before{content:'\02729\02729\02729\02729\02729'}



input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(1)::before{content:'\0272d'}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(2)::before{content:'\0272d\0272d'}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(3)::before{content:'\0272d\0272d\0272d'}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(4)::before{content:'\0272d\0272d\0272d\0272d'}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(5)::before{content:'\0272d\0272d\0272d\0272d\0272d'}

label {
  color: grey;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div star-buttons>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" id="_1"><label for="_1"></label><br>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="_2"><label for="_2"></label><br>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="3" id="_3"><label for="_3"></label><br>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="4"id ="_4"><label for="_4"></label><br>
  <input class="star-buttons" type="radio" name="radio" value="5" id="_5"><label for="_5"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep label:black and remove all
Try ! important 
It will stay black
Input is already display none so CSN does not matter