# How to get state of input field by clicking at parent <label> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an input checkbox field inside a label tag in html with bootstrap 4 and Angular 7. And i am calling a function on click on input checkbox and passing its state "($event.target.checked)" as one of the arguments. But all i receive is "undefined". On other hand if i call the function directly from input:checkbox i.e. without  tag ass the parent element then it works perfectly fine. But i need the former option to work.

Case 1:
">div>

> label (click)="onChange('father', $event.target.checked, 'diabetes')" class="btn btn-sm rounded-pill position-relative mb-2 mx-2">
>   input type="checkbox" name="diabetes" autocomplete="off"> Father
>   /label
>   "

Case 2:
">div>

> input type="checkbox" (click)="onChange('father', $event.target.checked, 'diabetes')" name="" id="">Father
>   /div>"

When i console both the above in my function, i receive undefined in 1st case with label outside the input field and it works just fine without label as shown in case 2 and provides true and false as results. Can anyone help me to get true and false values in case 1 also.

Comment: Please add your code too.

Comment: @randomSoul added code.. do check now

Comment: @AkshatSharma use `for` attribute to merge label and checkbox like this <label for="test">Demo</label> <input type="checkbox" id="test">

Comment: tried it.. still doesn't work.. when i apply click event on input:checkbox and use for with label, the event is not even fired.. its like i m not able to click at the input field at all.. only clicking at the label tag with which i m not able to access the state of input checkbox

Comment: check this link.. i want my code to run like this.. but for some reason it doesn't.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596641/8247912

Comment: refer this.. this a screen shot of my ui.. https://imgur.com/a/MCK35TS

Answer (score 0):

That's because you listen to click eventd on your checkbox.

Intsead, you should listen to `(change)` event :

```
(change)="onChange('father', $event, 'diabetes')"
```

This way, the function will be called everytime the value of the checkbox changes.

Comment: I have called click event on label tag in case 1 where i am not able to access the state of input field as it is a child tag of label tab. And If i apply click event or change event on input field in case 1, then the event is not even fired at all.

Comment: Did you read my answer ? You don't use the click event, you use the change event.

Comment: yes i did read ur reply.. and i applied the same to my code.. it still doesn't work... the event is not even fired at all..

Comment: Because your labels should have `for="checkboxID"` attributes to bind them to the checkboxes.

Comment: When we use input field inside a label, we dont need to use for attribute.. the label tag is already connected with the input field.. still i tried ur approach.. didn't work

Comment: And seeing your image, I can see the labels aren't in the checkbox. If it doesn't work, then please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: I have completed the task to firing the event of input:checkbox.. the only part remains is i m not able to apply active class of pink color on the label or checkbox as shown in the image.. and i have somewhere around 40 checkbox, so i dnt think this would be a great idea to create multiple boolean variables and apply ngClass based on them. any shorter way?

Comment: @AkshatSharma sure, once you provide a [mcve] I would gladly find another way of doing so.