# Why should HTML elements (input, textarea, and select) have associated labels?

Tags: html, label, webstorm

Can anyone please shed light on why (`input`, `textarea`, and `select`) should have an associated label?

I found a stackoverflow thread ([Should I put input elements inside a label element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-elements-inside-a-label-element)) that explains all the ways of associating `<input>` and `<label>`, but I didn't find any clear explanations of WHY a label must be associated.

##### Example

WebStorm (IDE) generates a "Missing associated label" warning for the input in this code:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
  <button id="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Applying auto-correction adds a label for the input:

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
  </label>
  <button id="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
</div>
```

The HTML works fine without the label, so why should I add it?

Comment: Note: it not necessarily to have `<label>` around your `<input>`. As long as it is associate with that input, e.g. `<label for="length">Length</label><input id="length" ...>`. P.S. And of course, you can just disable that inspection if you do not like it or think that it's unnecessary in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associated labels are meant for Acessibility. So when you run, for example, a lightouse Chrome check on a website it will point out missing labels in the "Acessibility" part of its report. Reason:

"Labels ensure that form controls are announced properly by assistive technologies, like screen readers".

So It is good to have them when you have a website that could be acessed by someone with a disability who cant properly read or see the content himself and needs a screen reader.

Comment: Interesting, I was not expecting that answer. I suppose programmatic screen readers can have a number of use cases, like search engine optimization. But wouldn't this open you up to bots?

Comment: Hmm i think it could maybe make a bots work slightly easier but an openly acessible Website should have additional protection against bots, like captcha and a block for proxy services or known hosting providers. So on a good website that souldn't create a safety problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add aria-label="" attribute to tag (input, textarea or select) if you want to hide this warning in IDE by JetBrains.