# How to add whitespace between CheckBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have problem adding spaces between CheckBoxes and text next to them. I want to have them intended a little bit, not next to each other without some space.

▓car▓wash▓next and have it like ▓ car ▓ wash ▓ next

CheckBoxes aren't fixed at size, they are gathered from database.

I have CheckBoxList like:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chBoxListManufacturer" runat="server" BackColor="LightBlue" BorderColor="Red" CellPadding="5" CssClas="mycheckbox"
       TextAlign="Right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BoxListManufacturer_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Css:`.mycheckbox {margin-right: 15px;}`

I was reading docs, but nothing works.

Comment: Use browser developer tool (Inspect Element) and identify HTML of checkboxlist. Apply CSS use margin to put space between controls.

Comment: This answer can be of help to you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681425/alignment-and-padding-for-aspcheckboxlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681425/alignment-and-padding-for-aspcheckboxlist)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with css class:

your checkboxlist here.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="test">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

css here.

```
.test td
{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

output.
[image: My output using same code]

Comment: I made it like you, but it seems like css is not reloading. If I set for instance background color to red, nothing changes. I updated my Code above like it looks now.

Comment: @Julius Marko i have edited the code and now its working i tested on my vs. In your case you only need padding-right. Plz let me know if it worked for you as well. Thanks

Comment: Not working. I think there is something that I'm not paying attention to. Looks like css don't change anything.

Comment: make sure you using <style> tags. anything else is same. its simple and should work. you can see my output with space in between and red box

Comment: I have CSS in my stylesheet file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trivial answer: put a `&nbsp;` after each checkbox, this will allow you some space between the control and the following label