# Strange scrolling behavior in IE with checkboxes in a scrollable div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I have a "multiselect" control that looks like this (sorry for the long id names, they are kinda autogenerated because this whole thing is being generated by a custom tag):

```
<div class="default-skin-outer" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectOuterDiv">
    <div class="default-control" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlDiv">
        <span class="default-icon-check-text" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlCheckWrapperSpan">
            <span class="default-icon default-icon-check" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlCheckIconSpan"></span><span class="default-icon default-icon-text" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlCheckTextSpan">Check All</span>
        </span>
        <span class="default-icon-uncheck-text" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlUncheckWrapperSpan">
            <span class="default-icon default-icon-uncheck" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlUncheckIconSpan"></span><span class="default-icon default-icon-text" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectControlUncheckTextSpan">Uncheck All</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="default-skin-inner" id="myMapSelect_multiSelectInnerDiv">
            <ul class="default-multiselect">
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect0" name="myMapSelect"> Zero
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect1" name="myMapSelect"> One
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect2" name="myMapSelect"> Two
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect3" name="myMapSelect"> Three
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect4" name="myMapSelect"> Four
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect5" name="myMapSelect"> Five
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="6" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect6" name="myMapSelect"> Six
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="default-multiselect">
                            <label class="default-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="7" class="default-checkbox" id="myMapSelect7" name="myMapSelect"> Seven
                            </label>
                        </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for this whole thing is:

```
div.default-skin-outer {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

div.default-skin-inner {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

div.default-control {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #555555;
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.default-multiselect {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.default-with-padding {
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li.default-multiselect {
    list-style-type: none;
}

label.default-label {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}

input.default-checkbox {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}

span.default-icon {
    background-image: url("/resources/authoring/jqueryui/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span.default-icon-text {
    width: auto;
    background: none;
}

span.default-icon-text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span.default-icon-check-text {
    float: left;
}

span.default-icon-uncheck-text {
    float: right;
}

span.default-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px;
}

span.default-icon-uncheck {
    background-position: -96px -128px;
}
```

This works beautifully in Firefox. The checkboxes scroll without any problem in the scrollable div. But when I looked at this in IE8, it looks terrible.

Firstly, the extra checkboxes bleed outside the main div. Secondly (and this is the really strange thing) when I use the scroll bar, the text scrolls, *but the checkboxes do not*. They simply stay in place while the text scrolls. I tried googling for a solution but was unable to come up with anything.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So I found out that if I remove the funky part in the checkbox styling:

```
vertical-align:bottom; 
position:relative; 
top: -1px; 
*overflow: hidden;
```

It works fine. But I put that in to make sure my [labels and checkboxes are lined up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers).

Oh yes as far as the compatibility view is concerned, this is IE8 running under compatibility mode.

In response to the comments about inherited styles, here are styles that the checkbox inherits:

```
input {
   border:1px solid #CFCFCF;
   color:#000000;
   font-family:Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif;
   font-size:12px;
   padding-left:4px;
}


li.default-multiselect {
   list-style-type:none;
}

ul.default-with-padding {
   white-space:nowrap;
}

table {
   empty-cells:show;
}

html, body {
   line-height:16px;
}
```

I don't see anything that could potentially interfere...

Comment: Doesn't happen for me.  Is IE 8 running in compatibility mode?  It does this automatically by default when you're viewing an intranet site.

Comment: I tried it as well, and it looks fine in IE8. Also fine in compatibility mode.

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen in compatibility mode for me, either.  Maybe the problem is with CSS or HTML outside of your posted question.

Comment: So I found out that if I remove the funky part in the checkbox (`vertical-align:bottom; position:relative; top: -1px; *overflow: hidden;`) it works fine. But I put that in to make sure my labels and checkboxes are lined up properly... so it looks like it's one or the other. I'm going to update the question.

@Jacob @Ray Really? That's strange... hmm I guess it might have to do with other CSS that is interfering with it? I will try it without any other styling.

Comment: Be sure to post how you get the labels and checkboxes to align properly.  That's always super-annoying.

Comment: @Jacob I posted a link to it. I got the solution from stackoverflow.

I also tried putting this in a page with no other styles, and it works like you said. It looks like something is interfering with the checkboxes... I just can't figure out what. Perhaps it is the interaction between the style of the container div, and whatever styles it is inheriting...

Comment: Have you checked it in IE's developer tool (similar to firebug). Maybe that can tell you where some stray styling is coming from. (Or is that where you got your list of inherited styles?)

Comment: Make sure your page validates and there's no malformed DIV tags or anything like that.  Could be something with the div's popping outside your container.

Comment: @Ray, yep that's where I got it from. Right now I'm unchecking inherited styles to see if I can narrow it down.
@Shawn it validates fine - it looks like some inherited style is interfering with it and causing this bizarre behavior.

Comment: Ok, I've figured this out. It's the `position:relative` in the the input style that's jacking it up. I removed that and the checkboxes still seems mostly aligned (just 1px off). This fix seems to make it work.

Since I'm new to stackoverflow, I'm not sure of the protocol in these cases... Now that I've solved the question myself, do I just update my question? Do I post my fix as an answer? Or is this comment sufficient?

Comment: You should post your own answer and accept it (once you're allowed to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some strange interaction between inherited styles and the styles I have defined. That much is clear from Jacob's and Ray's comments since they were able to slap this code onto a page and have it render fine in IE without any issues.

I was able to make it behave properly by removing `position:relative` from the `input.default-checkbox` style.

I'm assuming that some sort of bizarre interaction is making the checkboxes think they are positioned statically or absolutely (or something) due to which they don't scroll. At least I *think* that's the reason; someone may be able to provide a better reason and shed light on this. At any rate, by removing the `position:relative`, I was able to make the strange scrolling-behavior stop. Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  That definitely is an odd one.

Comment: Another fix is to add position:relative to the scrolling div's styling.

Comment: Thank you for posting this fix. I've run into exactly the same issue on old IE and it came down to `position:relative` styling on the checkbox as well. I ended up applying `position:relative` to the scrolling element as suggested by rossisdead.

Comment: You are amazing! The biggest problem of my life is now solved :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

As @rossisdead suggested, adding `position: relative` to the scrolling element solves the problem. I also had to add `position: relative` to the parent of the scrolling element.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `position: fixed` set on your checkboxes in any other stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to inherit that from anywhere.