# Right-Align and Vertical Align label with checkbox/radio button CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm very close and have this working in Safari, Firefox and IE8, however IE7 the labels and radio buttons do not align vertically.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="master-container">
    <fieldset id="test">
    <legend>This is a test of my CSS</legend>
         <ul class="inputlist">
             <li>
                 <label for="test1">Test 1</label>
                 <input name="test1" id="test1" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <label for="test2">Test 2</label>
                 <input name="test2" id="test2" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My CSS Is:

```css
html {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#master-container {
    width:615px;
    font-size:12px;
}

ul.inputlist {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul.inputlist li {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
ul.inputlist li label {
    width:30px;
    text-align:right; 
    margin-right:7px;
    float:left;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the suggestion to check the rest of my html and css.  I updated the code above and now it accurately demonstrates the problem.  If I take `font-size` out of `#master-container` it lines up but then it is not the proper font-size.  I tried to add a `font-size` to `ul.inputlist li input` but that didn't help.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: I can probably figure this out, but is there more code that you are working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This could be what you needed:**

```
label, input {vertical-align: baseline;}
```

Both element with the same property, will help. Also baseline works similar. middle works different in IE7.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers i hope it can help you!

Comment: Hi Allan, I had to take out a *{margin:0px;padding:0px;} I had, give the ul.inputlist li a line-height of 18px and then use vertical-align:baseline on the label.  Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What about adding "clear: both" to the li elements:

```
ul.inputlist li{width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;clear:both}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work either.  Any other ideas?

Comment: When I tested the markup/CSS above, it doesn't work for me in Firefox (but it does in IE7), so I feel like there must be something else going on. Is there more markup/CSS?

Another possible solution is to add more to margin-bottom, say 20px or so.

Comment: I added the code that is causing the problem.  Thanks for your suggestion!