# How to style a checkbox using CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to style a checkbox using the following:

```html
<input type="checkbox" style="border:2px dotted #00f;display:block;background:#ff0000;" />
```

But the style is not applied. The checkbox still displays its default style. How do I give it the specified style?

Comment: I [wrote a tutorial](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs) about how to customize checkboxes and radios with CSS only, as well as create on/off switches. Check it out!

Comment: https://github.com/avatec/avatec-bootstrap3-custom-checkbox ready to use plugin

Comment: Whatever decision you make for styling checkboxes or radio buttons via CSS please make sure that they are accessible. As of this comment I believe only 2 of the 33 answers so far are accessible. For the rest of the answers you're cutting off most, if not all accessibility. (`ctrl+f` "accessibility")

Comment: There's a native CSS property for this now, skip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69164710/2756409).

Comment: Along with the `accent-color` CSS that (in most implementations) affects only the color when checked, it's also possible to further customise the background color when unchecked by using CSS `filters`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248096/690188) (very useful for dark mode styles where the white of empty checkboxes don't fit in).

Answer (score 902, accepted):

UPDATE:

The below answer references the state of things before widespread availability of CSS 3. In modern browsers (including Internet Explorer 9 and later) it is more straightforward to create checkbox replacements with your preferred styling, without using JavaScript.

Here are some useful links:

- [Creating Custom Form Checkboxes with Just CSS](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)
- [Easy CSS Checkbox Generator](http://csscheckbox.com)
- [Stuff You Can Do With The Checkbox Hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)
- [Implementing Custom Checkboxes and Radio Buttons with CSS3](http://www.css3.com/implementing-custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-css3/)
- [How to Style a Checkbox With CSS](https://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-style-a-checkbox-with-css)

It is worth noting that the fundamental issue has not changed. You still can't apply styles (borders, etc.) directly to the checkbox element and have those styles affect the display of the HTML checkbox. What has changed, however, is that it's now possible to hide the actual checkbox and replace it with a styled element of your own, using nothing but CSS. In particular, because CSS now has a widely supported `:checked` selector, you can make your replacement correctly reflect the checked status of the box.

---

OLDER ANSWER

Here's [a useful article about styling checkboxes](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/).  Basically, that writer found that it varies tremendously from browser to browser, and that many browsers always display the default checkbox no matter how you style it. So there really isn't an easy way.

It's not hard to imagine a workaround where you would use JavaScript to overlay an image on the checkbox and have clicks on that image cause the real checkbox to be checked. Users without JavaScript would see the default checkbox.

Edited to add: here's [a nice script that does this for you](https://web.archive.org/web/20160430165815/http://ryanfait.com:80/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/#); it hides the real checkbox element, replaces it with a styled span, and redirects the click events.

Comment: This answer is getting old! The primary link leads to a site comparing IE6 and IE7 styles...

Comment: Fair point -- and the basic point isn't really true anymore, in modern browsers.  I've updated with some newer links, but left the original as a resource for older browsers.

Comment: [Easy CSS Checkbox Generator](http://csscheckbox.com/), was really easy and n00b friendly. Comes with GUI for customized creation too! Well appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm interested in the old answer because I want this feature to be compatible with IE8+ & other browsers (chrome, firefox & safari). However I cannot find much feedback regarding the plugin you recommend http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: this js plugin seems pretty good. Compatible with IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari & mobile browsers https://github.com/arthurgouveia/prettyCheckable/

Comment: note that prettyCheckable is not "compatible" with this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers

Comment: Most of these links go to pages which seem to think a label should be blank. I would recommend this codepen: http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp instead.

Comment: This is not a very useful answer - it's just a list of articles, most of which are very old now.

Answer (score 176):

You can achieve quite a cool custom checkbox effect by using the new abilities that come with the `:after` and `:before` pseudo classes. The advantage to this, is: You don't need to add anything more to the DOM, just the standard checkbox.

Note this will only work for compatible browsers. I believe this is related to the fact that some browsers do not allow you to set `:after` and `:before` on input elements. Which unfortunately means for the moment only WebKit browsers are supported. Firefox + Internet Explorer will still allow the checkboxes to function, just unstyled, and this will hopefully change in the future (the code does not use vendor prefixes).

**This is a WebKit browser solution only (Chrome, Safari, Mobile browsers)**

**[See Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMuPw/15/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    $('div').html(Math.random());
  });
});
```

```css
/* Main Classes */
.myinput[type="checkbox"]:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  content: "";
  background: #FFF;
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 2px;
  top: -11px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #B3B3B3 #dcddde #dcddde #B3B3B3;
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #B1B6BE 0%, #FFF 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAQAAABuW59YAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAIGNIUk0AAHolAACAgwAA+f8AAIDpAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXb5JfxUYAAAB2SURBVHjaAGkAlv8A3QDyAP0A/QD+Dam3W+kCAAD8APYAAgTVZaZCGwwA5wr0AvcA+Dh+7UX/x24AqK3Wg/8nt6w4/5q71wAAVP9g/7rTXf9n/+9N+AAAtpJa/zf/S//DhP8H/wAA4gzWj2P4lsf0JP0A/wADAHB0Ngka6UmKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'), linear-gradient(135deg, #B1B6BE 0%, #FFF 100%);
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:disabled:after {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(0.4);
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:hover:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAQAAABuW59YAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAIGNIUk0AAHolAACAgwAA+f8AAIDpAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXb5JfxUYAAAB2SURBVHjaAGkAlv8A3QDyAP0A/QD+Dam3W+kCAAD8APYAAgTVZaZCGwwA5wr0AvcA+Dh+7UX/x24AqK3Wg/8nt6w4/5q71wAAVP9g/7rTXf9n/+9N+AAAtpJa/zf/S//DhP8H/wAA4gzWj2P4lsf0JP0A/wADAHB0Ngka6UmKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'), linear-gradient(135deg, #8BB0C2 0%, #FFF 100%);
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):hover:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #8BB0C2 0%, #FFF 100%);
  border-color: #85A9BB #92C2DA #92C2DA #85A9BB;
}

.myinput[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):hover:before {
  border-color: #3D7591;
}

/* Large checkboxes */
.myinput.large {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.myinput.large[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.myinput.large[type="checkbox"]:after {
  top: -20px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

/* Custom checkbox */
.myinput.large.custom[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAk0lEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwcAD+OzN/oMwshjRBoA0Gr8+DcbIhhBlAEyz+qZZ/7WPryHNAGTNMOxpJvo/w0/uP0kGgGwGaZbrKgfTGnLc/0nyAgiDbEY2BCRGdCDCnA2yGeYVog0Aae5MV4c7Gzk6CRqAbDM2w/EaQEgzXgPQnU2SAcTYjNMAYm3GaQCxNuM0gFwMAPUKd8XyBVDcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'), linear-gradient(135deg, #B1B6BE 0%, #FFF 100%);
}

.myinput.large.custom[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:hover:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAk0lEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwcAD+OzN/oMwshjRBoA0Gr8+DcbIhhBlAEyz+qZZ/7WPryHNAGTNMOxpJvo/w0/uP0kGgGwGaZbrKgfTGnLc/0nyAgiDbEY2BCRGdCDCnA2yGeYVog0Aae5MV4c7Gzk6CRqAbDM2w/EaQEgzXgPQnU2SAcTYjNMAYm3GaQCxNuM0gFwMAPUKd8XyBVDcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'), linear-gradient(135deg, #8BB0C2 0%, #FFF 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Normal:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Small:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="myinput" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="myinput" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="myinput" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" class="myinput" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Large:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="myinput large" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="myinput large" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="myinput large" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" class="myinput large" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custom icon:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="myinput large custom" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="myinput large custom" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="myinput large custom" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" class="myinput large custom" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Bonus Webkit style flipswitch fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dv904vn1/2/)

```js
$(function() {
  var f = function() {
    $(this).next().text($(this).is(':checked') ? ':checked' : ':not(:checked)');
  };
  $('input').change(f).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.flipswitch {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.flipswitch:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  color: black;
  border: #888 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.flipswitch:after {
  left: 2%;
  content: "OFF";
}

.flipswitch:checked:after {
  left: 53%;
  content: "ON";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Webkit friendly mobile-style checkbox/flipswitch</h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="flipswitch" /> &nbsp;
<span></span>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="flipswitch" /> &nbsp;
<span></span>
```

Comment: Firefox 33.1/Linux: The fiddle shows just default checkboxes. Nothing looks different.

Comment: @robsch This is clearly pointed out in the original post. Version of firefox or OS is irrelevant, it does not work in firefox. "FF + IE will still allow the check-boxes to function, just un-styled..."

Comment: A good approach. But not all browsers doing it good. Only Chrome has the best output as far as I examined.

Comment: Very nice. However... It is again an IE 5.x approach. Webkit only. Because it doesn't always follow the rules... That's the entire problem with webkit browsers.

Comment: I get the default checkboxes in Firefox 58 and IE11 on Win too.

Comment: @AndriiBogachenko On the very contrary, having a detailed example is excellent to a quality answer.

Comment: i believe this is invalid and webkit/blink are violating the spec.  `::before` and `::after` only work on containers; checkboxes are replaced elements.  same reason you can't use them on images.

Answer (score 169):

### Before you begin (as of Jan 2015)

The original question and answer are now ~5 years old. As such, this is a little bit of an update.

Firstly, there are a number of approaches when it comes to styling checkboxes. The basic tenet is:

1. You will need to hide the default checkbox control which is styled by your browser, and cannot be overridden in any meaningful way using CSS.
2. With the control hidden, you will still need to be able to detect and toggle its checked state.
3. The checked state of the checkbox will need to be reflected by styling a new element.

### The solution (in principle)

The above can be accomplished by a number of means — and you will often hear that using CSS3 pseudo-elements is the right way. Actually, there is no real right or wrong way, it depends on the approach most suitable for the context you will be using it in. That said, I have a preferred one.

1. Wrap your checkbox in a `label` element. This will mean that even when it is hidden, you can still toggle its checked state by clicking anywhere within the label.
2. Hide your checkbox.
3. Add a new element *after* the checkbox which you will style accordingly. It must appear after the checkbox so it can be selected using CSS and styled dependent on the `:checked` state. CSS cannot select 'backwards'.

### The solution (in code)

```css
label input {
  visibility: hidden;/* <-- Hide the default checkbox. The rest is to hide and allow tabbing, which display:none prevents */
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label span {/* <-- Style the artificial checkbox */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
[type=checkbox]:checked + span {/* <-- Style its checked state */
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <span></span>
  Checkbox label text
</label>
```

### Refinement (using icons)

"But hey!" I hear you shout. What about if I want to show a nice little tick or cross in the box? And I don't want to use background images!

Well, this is where CSS3's pseudo-elements can come into play. These support the `content` property which allows you to inject [Unicode icons](http://unicode-table.com/en/) representing either state. Alternatively, you could use a third party font icon source such as font awesome (though make sure you also set the relevant `font-family`, e.g. to `FontAwesome`)

```css
label input {
  display: none; /* Hide the default checkbox */
}

/* Style the artificial checkbox */
label span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Style its checked state...with a ticked icon */
[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {
  content: '\2714';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <span></span>
  Checkbox label text
</label>
```

Comment: What you've described is EXACTLY what I've described.

Comment: Except for: simplified HTML, simplified CSS, detailed explanation.

Comment: @AnthonyHayward - updated answer, this was due to using display:none which does not instantiate the control in a tabbable way, I've changed

Comment: I was struggling to find an example in which the checkbox was inside of the label rather than before/after it. This is a very well documented and explained solution. It would be great to see this answer updated for January 2016.

Comment: Still not tabbable with `display: none`.

Comment: Replace `visibility: hidden;` with `opacity: 0 !important;` if you're still having trouble with tabbing.

Comment: @jabacchetta - note that per the CSS spec, the use of `!important` is not recommended, especially for production code (however, real world needs may justify)

Comment: Yeah I usually stay away from `!important`. But it appears to be the ONLY way to keep tabbing with some of these checkbox designs. I actually came across that from looking at the code used in some of Semantic UI's checkboxes.

Answer (score 154):

There is a way to do this using just CSS. We can (ab)use the `label` element and style that element instead. The caveat is that this will not work for Internet Explorer 8 and lower versions.

```css
.myCheckbox input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.myCheckbox span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: url("link_to_image");
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
  background: url("link_to_another_image");
}
```

```html
<label for="test">Label for my styled "checkbox"</label>
<label class="myCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow this will work for any browser that supports the :checked pseudo-class, which IE8 does NOT support. You can check if this works with http://selectivizr.com - which adds support for :checked and friends.

Comment: In other words, IE9 and later versions supports :checked.

Comment: There is a polyfill for IE8 and below: https://github.com/rdebeasi/checked-polyfill

Comment: It's working, but first time it flickers. Why is it happening?

Comment: I believe hidden `input`s never take keyboard focus, so these are unreachable by keyboard.

Comment: Updated example to use `position: relative` and a negative `z-index` instead.

Comment: Superb work around, worked like a charm with a few mods for my design. Thank-you!

Comment: @BlakePettersson mind to make a working snippet for your answer?

Comment: Why the `z-index` stuff and not just `<input hidden>`?

Comment: Works if your checkbox has an id.

Comment: @BlakePettersson Your word choice "(ab)use" might be accurate. Do you know if this particular use of the `label` tag violates WC3's WCAG accessibility guidelines (and potentially accessibility interface software?)

Answer (score 129):

### Modern *accessible* solution - use `accent-color`

Use the new [**`accent-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) property and make certain to meet a proper [contrast ratio](https://contrast-ratio.com/) of 3:1 to ensure [accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49412660/4826740). This also works for `radio` buttons.

```css
.red-input {
    accent-color: #9d3039;
    height: 20px; /* not needed */
    width: 20px; /* not needed */
}
```

```html
<input class="red-input" type="checkbox" />

<!-- Radio button example -->
<input class="red-input" type="radio" />
```

---

### Old answer, I only recommend this if you need more customization than the above offers:

I have been scrolling and scrolling and **tons** of these answers simply throw accessibility out the door and [violate WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/F78) in more than one way. I threw in radio buttons since most of the time when you're using custom checkboxes you want custom radio buttons too.

**Fiddles**:

- [Checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/2cs0dj54/) - pure CSS - free from 3rd party libraries
- [Radio buttons](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/2bgknq68/) - pure CSS - free from 3rd party libraries
- [Checkboxes*](http://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/qxakwcy3/) that use FontAwesome but could be swapped with Glyphicons, etc. easily

Late to the party but somehow this is still difficult in <s>2019</s>, <s>2020</s>, 2021 so I have added my three solutions which are **accessible** and **easy** to drop in.

These  are  all **JavaScript free**, **accessible**, and **external library free***...

If you want to plug-n-play with any of these just copy the style sheet from the fiddles, edit the color codes in the CSS to fit your needs, and be on your way. You can add a custom svg checkmark icon if you want for the checkboxes. I've added lots of comments for those non-CSS'y folks.

If you have long text or a small container and are encountering text wrapping underneath the checkbox or radio button input then just convert to divs [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/ucq21nkx/8/).

**Longer explanation:**
I needed a solution that does not violate WCAG, doesn't rely on JavaScript or external libraries, and that does not break keyboard navigation like tabbing or spacebar to select, that allows focus events, a solution that allows for disabled checkboxes that are both checked and unchecked, and finally a solution where I can customize the look of the checkbox however I want with different `background-color`'s, `border-radius`, `svg` backgrounds, etc.

I used some combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876109/4826740) from @Jan Turoň to come up with my own solution which seems to work quite well. I've done a radio button fiddle that uses a lot of the same code from the checkboxes in order to make this work with radio buttons too.

I am still learning accessibility so if I missed something please drop a comment and I will try to correct it.

Here is a code example of my checkboxes:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Text color for the label */
input[type="checkbox"]+span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

/* Checkbox un-checked style */
input[type="checkbox"]+span:before {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

/* Checked checkbox style (in this case the background is green #e7ffba, change this to change the color) */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:before {
  /* NOTE: Replace the url with a path to an SVG of a checkmark to get a checkmark icon */
  background-image: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.5.6/collection/build/ionicons/svg/ios-checkmark.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /* The size of the checkmark icon, you may/may not need this */
  background-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #e7ffba;
  color: white;
}

/* Adding a dotted border around the active tabbed-into checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"]:focus+span:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)+span:hover:before {
  /* Visible in the full-color space */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);

  /* Visible in Windows high-contrast themes
     box-shadow will be hidden in these modes and
     transparency will not be hidden in high-contrast
     thus box-shadow will not show but the outline will
     providing accessibility */
  outline-color: transparent; /*switch to transparent*/
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dotted;
  }


/* Disabled checkbox styles */
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+span {
  cursor: default;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Styles specific to this fiddle that you do not need */
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  NOTE: Replace the url for the background-image in CSS with a path to an SVG in your solution or CDN. This one was found from a quick google search for a checkmark icon cdn
</h1>

<p>You can easily change the background color, checkbox symbol, border-radius, etc.</p>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Try using tab and space</span>
</label>

<br>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
  <span>Disabled Checked Checkbox</span>
</label>

<br>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled>
  <span>Disabled Checkbox</span>
</label>
<br>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Normal Checkbox</span>
</label>

<br>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Another Normal Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

Comment: It's one thing to update the answer to provide a new solution, although kinda iffy when another answer already provides that solution. It's another thing altogether to delete your existing content and show only the new solution that is already entirely provided by a separate answer. If all that's left is the new solution copying another answer, then the post should just be deleted.

Comment: So glad I found this. All I wanted were different colors for the checkboxes. Didn't read further since it's 2022.

Answer (score 109):

I always use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` for changing the appearance of checkboxes and radio buttons. it's works like a charm.

Refer this [**link**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) for more info

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/NWPrZqr)

**Steps**

1. Hide the default checkbox using css rules like `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` or `position:absolute;left:-9999px` etc.
2. Create a fake checkbox using `:before` element and pass either an empty or a non-breaking space `'\00a0'`;
3. When the checkbox is in `:checked` state, pass the unicode `content: "\2713"`, which is a checkmark;
4. Add `:focus` style to make the checkbox accessible.
5. Done

Here is how I did it.

```css
.box {
  background: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
    outline: rgb(59, 153, 252) auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cb">
      <label for="c1">Option 01</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cb">
      <label for="c2">Option 02</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cb">
      <label for="c3">Option 03</label>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Much more stylish using `:before` and `:after`**

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;  
}

.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.checkbox {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0.00000001;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.checkbox label {
    position: relative;
}
.checkbox label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    transition: transform 0.28s ease;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #7bbe72;
}
.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7bbe72;
    border-left: 2px solid #7bbe72;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    transition: transform ease 0.25s;
    will-change: transform;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::before {
    color: #7bbe72;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
}

.checkbox label {
    min-height: 34px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
.checkbox label span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="" value="">
     <label for="checkbox"><span>Checkbox</span></label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="" value="">
     <label for="checkbox2"><span>Checkbox</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 61):

<s>I'd follow the advice of [SW4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/27779075#27779075)</s>. Not anymore: [Volomike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411758/343721) is far superior to all the answers here (note my suggested improvement in the comment to the answer). Proceed reading this answer if you are curious about alternative approaches, which this answer comments.

---

First of all, hide the checkbox and to cover it with a custom span, suggesting this HTML:

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>send newsletter</span>
</label>
```

The wrap in label neatly allows clicking the text without the need of "for-id" attribute linking. However,

### Do not hide it using `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`

It works by clicking or tapping, but that is a lame way to use checkboxes. Some people still use much more effective <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus, <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate, and hiding with that method disables it. If the form is long, one will save someone's wrists to use `tabindex` or `accesskey` attributes. And if you observe the system checkbox behavior, there is a decent shadow on hover. The well styled checkbox should follow this behavior.

[cobberboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/24524798#24524798) recommends [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) which is usually better than bitmap since fonts are scalable vectors. Working with the HTML above, I'd suggest these CSS rules:

1. **Hide checkboxes**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
   ```

   I use just negative `z-index` since my example uses big enough checkbox skin to cover it fully. I don't recommend `left: -999px` since it is not reusable in every layout. [Bushan wagh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/23198205#23198205) provides a bulletproof way to hide it and convince the browser to use tabindex, so it is a good alternative. Anyway, both is just a hack. The proper way today is `appearance: none`, see [Joost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/34061013#34061013):

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
    }
   ```
2. **Style checkbox label**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"] + span {
      font: 16pt sans-serif;
      color: #000;
    }
   ```
3. **Add checkbox skin**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
      font: 16pt FontAwesome;
      content: '\00f096';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 16pt;
      padding: 2px 0 0 3px;
      margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
   ```

`\00f096` is Font Awesome's `square-o`, padding is adjusted to provide even dotted outline on focus (see below).

4. **Add checkbox checked skin**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
      content: '\00f046';
    }
   ```

`\00f046` is Font Awesome's `check-square-o`, which is not the same width as `square-o`, which is the reason for the width style above.

5. **Add focus outline**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus + span:before {
      outline: 1px dotted #aaa;
    }
   ```

   Safari doesn't provide this feature (see @Jason Sankey's comment), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975282/343721) for Safari-only CSS
6. **Set gray color for disabled checkbox**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span {
      color: #999;
    }
   ```
7. **Set hover shadow on non-disabled checkbox**

   ```css
    input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled) + span:hover:before {
      text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #77F;
    }
   ```

---

### Test it on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qjozqtc/1/)

Try to hover the mouse over the checkboxes and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move and <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle.

Comment: Upvote for covering the focus issue: customisations like this shouldn't remove basic functionality.  Note though that Safari doesn't give keyboard focus to checkboxes (even default ones), that confused me momentarily when implementing a solution that included focus handling.

Comment: Most of these answers ignore accessibility. I love that this answer keeps that in tact.

Comment: I ended up doing a spin off of this answer in mine. I could not rely upon external libraries like FontAwesome, so I baked some advice from this answer into my own custom solution and kept everything accessible like this answer does. I also included a radio button design: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570835/4826740 Thanks Jan for the awesome help!

Comment: @maxshuty I like your approach, too: when someone creates a library, oftentimes it is just a confession that he can't code simple in the native language of his choice. IMHO FontAwesome screwed up with their Free plan using javascript to load the font, but I still like them as they stay open source and free license. I usually end up font-forging subset of free icons I need in particular project (usually max 5kB). I would gladly pay if they saved me the effort, but not the insane 99$ per year as they propose in their Pro plan.

Answer (score 52):

The [CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#widget-accent) adds support for this (finally) via a new solution called `accent-color`, and it's *actually* quite simple, unlike pretty much every other answer here:

```css
input {
    accent-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Set whatever CSS color (e.g. named value, hex code, etc.) you want as the value of `accent-color`, and it will be applied.

This currently works in Chrome (v93+), Edge (v93+), Firefox (v92+), Opera (v79+), and Safari (v15.4+).

Note: Edge, Chrome, and Opera (and possibly Safari; I can't test that) currently don't support alpha channel values via `rgba()` either (the RGB values of `rgba()` will still "work"; the alpha channel will simply be ignored by the browser). See [MDN Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color#browser_compatibility) for more information.

Comment: Nice! But could it be, that `accent-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` ignores the alpha channel? My checkbox background is simply black.

Comment: @Flippowitsch On Firefox 92.0 I see the correct alpha channel. Looks like Chrome 93 and Edge 93 don't support alpha channels for it quite yet... good catch! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Since it's been a year and Chromium has not added alpha channel support yet, I have posted on the Chromium tracker for this property to ask about any intent to ship support for that feature: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/WwYkLjbGhoA

Comment: It seems like Chromium's lack of alpha support is intentional; their implementation of accent-color renders the entire checkbox invisible with an alpha transparency value of zero. They're re-investigating it and looking into copying Firefox' method as a fix to allow alpha support: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1200932

Comment: `accent-color` works until the checkbox is disabled, then colors revert to browser defaults (unless there's some other CSS attribute?)  Confirmed with MS Edge Version 120.0.2210.91, probably also in modern Chrome.

Comment: @BobHy `accent-color` only applies to the _checked_ format of a checkbox, so how exactly would you expect it to even be possible for `disabled`? In other words, of course it doesn't work when the checkbox is disabled! The `disabled` property also applies its own styles, I believe, so you could potentially override those, but I haven't looked into that.

Answer (score 49):

With pure CSS, nothing fancy with `:before` and `:after`, no transforms, you can turn off the default appearance and then style it with an inline background image like the following example. This works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and now Edge (Chromium Edge).

```css
INPUT[type=checkbox]:focus
{
    outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

INPUT[type=checkbox]
{
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 2px;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

INPUT[type=checkbox]:checked
{
    background-color: #409fd6;
    background: #409fd6 url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwAKAIABAP////3cnSH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAALAAoAAAIUjH+AC73WHIsw0UCjglraO20PNhYAOw==") 3px 3px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> I Agree To Terms &amp; Conditions</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Great idea, Volomike. Some improvements: 1) set width and height to 1em and top to 0.2em to make it scallable with the font size. 2) set background to center/cover to scale with the size. Also, the `background-color` in your code is redundant. 3) remove the `cursor: pointer` - keep the default behavior and let user set it in their stylesheet.

Comment: You can also just use: `all: unset`, for the checkbox, which has almost identical support out of the box, without requiring the browser-specific flags, and the caveats that come along with `appearance`. :)

Answer (score 38):

## Simple to implement and easily customizable solution

After a lot of search and testing I got this solution which is simple to implement and easier to customize. **In this solution**:

1. You don't need external libraries and files
2. You don't need to add
   extra HTML in your page
3. You don't need to change checkbox names
   and id

Simple put the flowing CSS at the top of your page and all checkboxes style will change like this:

[image]

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after,
input[type=checkbox]::after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #00BFF0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid #00BFF0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after,
input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
  content: "\2714";
  padding: -5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<label for="checkbox1">Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: Nice solution. But I dont see it working on Firefox, IE or Edge (there is no checkbox)

Comment: @Jono I've updated the answer, please try it now.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen still no checkbox on Firefox (Mac, 97.0.2) - I am not able to check IE or Edge

Comment: I see a huge checkbox on Edge (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOhLI.png), but yes it is blank in Firefox (no blue checkbox shown or even clickable). cc @Jono IE is not supported by Stack Overflow and Stack Snippets won't run on that browser. Nor will most other code sandbox sites like JSFiddle or CodePen, to my knowledge...

Answer (score 36):

You can style checkboxes with a little trickery using the `label` element an example is below:

```css
.checkbox > input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
}

.checkbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  right: 10px;
  content: 'no';
  color: #E53935;
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 0;
}

.checkbox:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  left: 10px;
  content: 'yes';
  color: #43A047;
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 0;
}

.checkbox label {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  left: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="checkbox1"></label>
</div>
```

And a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w6y7u3na/)** for the above code. Note that some CSS doesn't work in older versions of browsers, but I'm sure there are some fancy JavaScript examples out there!

Comment: How to use it where the checkbox has it's won label?

Comment: @Metaphor Just add a second label. You can apply multiple labels to the same element (e.g. they can use the same `for` attribute value).

Answer (score 29):

You can avoid adding extra markup. This works everywhere except IE via setting CSS `appearance`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  /* Styling checkbox */
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I like this approach - it is a bit hacky as you shouldn't ever really use appearance in css but it is much cleaner than some of the other answers using before and after. And for something like this I feel JavaScript is complete overkill.

Answer (score 25):

Recently I found a quite interesting solution to the problem.

You could use `appearance: none;` to turn off the checkbox's default style and then write your own over it like described [here (Example 4)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#appearance-switching).

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #878787;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Unfortunately browser support is quite bad for the `appearance` option. From my personal testing I only got Opera and Chrome working correctly. But this would be the way to go to keep it simple when better support comes or you only want to use Chrome/Opera.

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxv6dunu/)

["Can I use?" link](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance)

Comment: Indeed `appearance` is just what we need for this; just bear in mind it ["is non-standard and is not on a standards track"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance).

Comment: I've added a little more styling to make it more closely match chrome tick box. So its easily interchangeable: - http://jsfiddle.net/inspiraller/g8mo1nh3/1/

Comment: One of the downsides here is that you lose the "check" part of "checkbox". It's now just a box that changes color, which is far less clear from a UX/accessibility perspective as to what it is, and what's happening when you click it.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use icon fonts (such as FontAwesome) since it's easy to modify their colours with CSS, and they scale really well on high pixel-density devices. So here's another pure CSS variant, using similar techniques to those above.

(Below is a static image so you can visualize the result; see [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cunneen/D2mhh/2/) for an interactive version.)

[image: Checkbox example]

As with other solutions, it uses the `label` element. An adjacent `span` holds our checkbox character.

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
  font-family: FontAwesome; /* Use an icon font for the checkbox */
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {
  position: relative;
  left: -999em; /* Hide the real checkbox */
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f096"; /* In fontawesome, is an open square (fa-square-o) */
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f046"; /* fontawesome checked box (fa-check-square-o) */
}

/* ==== Optional - colors and padding to make it look nice === */
body {
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  color: #D35400;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 4em; /* Set this to whatever size you want */
}

span.bigcheck {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">
    Cheese
    <input type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes" />
    <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
  </label>
</span>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cunneen/D2mhh/2/) for it.

Comment: ....what you described is the same as previous answers from Bhushan wagh, Jake, Jonathan Hodgson and Blake ;)

Comment: @SW4 I've made reference to that fact, except this answer uses icon fonts (which none of the previous answers had). The first paragraph makes that pretty clear.

Comment: You need to replace `font-family: FontAwesome;` with `font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';`, and update unicode content if you want to make it work in new version.

Answer (score 17):

### My solution

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: #2aa1c0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><br>
<input type="checkbox" checked><br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled><br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked><br>
```

Comment: If someone could advice why my text is not aligned after, I'd love to know! CSS beginner here.

Comment: Checked the entire thread and appearance seems to be key as well as after. Also, if someone need to have a larger checkbox, then this solution will work just fine. Just play around with top, left, width, height and border-width. Works in modern browsers according to caniuse.com. I'm writing this comment in May 2021 for my future self. :)

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use `appearance: none` on modern browsers, so that there is no default styling and all your styles are applied properly:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This copies the solution from Joost's answer from 2015.

Comment: @TylerH Do you know what *copy* means? The fact that we both used `appearance ` doesn't mean that the answer is the same. My code is definitely smaller and cleaner and I also add that the solution works on modern browsers.

Comment: I do, in fact, know what copy means. [Joost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061013/2756409) suggests using `appearance: none` as a solution. This answer also suggests using `appearance: none` as a solution. Since it suggests the same solution, it's a copy. It does not have to be a *literal character-for-character facsimile* to be a copy. Next time, please read all existing answers before posting your own, to avoid simply repeating information.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple CSS solution without any jQuery or JavaScript code.

I am using FontAwseome icons but you can use any image

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
  content: @fa-var-square-o;
  visibility: visible;
  /*font-size: 12px;*/
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  content: @fa-var-check-square-o;
}
```

Comment: Unlike most of the other answers, this one doesn't require creation of additional `label` or `span` elements.  It just works!

Comment: Could you show an example or a demo, or at least the HTML part, with which this CSS code is working?  @aWebDeveloper

Comment: @aWebDeveloper making inane edits to bump an answer or question to the home page is against the rules.

Comment: @aWebDeveloper You edited an old answer on an inactive question, which bumps it to the front page and provides a link straight to your answer. This is fine if you have pertinent info to add or change in an answer. All you did was embed one of your sentences in a quote block, which isn't useful to anyone.

Comment: should work @VadimOvchinnikov... nothing here is chrome specific

Comment: @aWebDeveloper pseudoselectors for `input` work only in Chrome. If you don't agree can you please share simple demo i.e. in jsfiddle that works not only in Chrome? Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/7e08adkj/ You'll see "ABC" only in Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

From my googling, this is the easiest way for checkbox styling. Just add `:after` and `:checked:after` CSS based on your design.

```css
body{
  background: #DDD;
}
span{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #00BFF0;
    width: 14px;
    height: 19px;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 0 3px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "\2714";
    display: unset;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> <span>Select Text</span>
```

Answer (score 7):

Modify the checkbox style with plain CSS. This does not require any JavaScript or HTML manipulation:

```css
.form input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "\f096";
  opacity: 1 !important;
  margin-top: -25px;
  appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.form input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  content: "\f046";
}

.form input[type="checkbox"] {
  font-size: 22px;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov We have one solution which requires to following some html structure..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305780/how-to-style-css-checkboxes-with-font-awesome/41187009#41187009

Answer (score 6):

Yikes! All these workarounds have led me to the conclusion that the HTML checkbox kind of sucks if you want to style it.

As a forewarning, this isn't a CSS implementation. I just thought I'd share the workaround I came up with in case anyone else might find it useful.

---

I used the HTML5 `canvas` element.

The upside to this is that you don't have to use external images and can probably save some bandwidth.

The downside is that if a browser for some reason can't render it correctly, then there's no fallback. Though whether this remains an issue in 2017 is debatable.

### Update

I found the old code quite ugly, so I decided to give it a rewrite.

```
Object.prototype.create = function(args){
    var retobj = Object.create(this);

    retobj.constructor(args || null);

    return retobj;
}

var Checkbox = Object.seal({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    state: 0,
    document: null,
    parent: null,
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,

    /*
     * args:
     * name      default             desc.
     *
     * width     15                  width
     * height    15                  height
     * document  window.document     explicit document reference
     * target    this.document.body  target element to insert checkbox into
     */
    constructor: function(args){
        if(args === null)
            args = {};

        this.width = args.width || 15;
        this.height = args.height || 15;
        this.document = args.document || window.document;
        this.parent = args.target || this.document.body;
        this.canvas = this.document.createElement("canvas");
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        this.canvas.width = this.width;
        this.canvas.height = this.height;
        this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.ev_click(this), false);
        this.parent.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.draw();
    },

    ev_click: function(self){
        return function(unused){
            self.state = !self.state;
            self.draw();
        }
    },

    draw_rect: function(color, offset){
        this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
        this.ctx.fillRect(offset, offset,
                this.width - offset * 2, this.height - offset * 2);
    },

    draw: function(){
        this.draw_rect("#CCCCCC", 0);
        this.draw_rect("#FFFFFF", 1);

        if(this.is_checked())
            this.draw_rect("#000000", 2);
    },

    is_checked: function(){
        return !!this.state;
    }
});
```

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5und7njs/1).

The new version uses prototypes and differential inheritance to create an efficient system for creating checkboxes. To create a checkbox:

```
var my_checkbox = Checkbox.create();
```

This will immediately add the checkbox to the DOM and hook up the events. To query whether a checkbox is checked:

```
my_checkbox.is_checked(); // True if checked, else false
```

Also important to note is that I got rid of the loop.

### Update 2

Something I neglected to mention in the last update is that using the canvas has more advantages than just making a checkbox that looks however you want it to look. You could also create *multi-state* checkboxes, if you wanted to.

```
Object.prototype.create = function(args){
    var retobj = Object.create(this);

    retobj.constructor(args || null);

    return retobj;
}

Object.prototype.extend = function(newobj){
    var oldobj = Object.create(this);

    for(prop in newobj)
        oldobj[prop] = newobj[prop];

    return Object.seal(oldobj);
}

var Checkbox = Object.seal({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    state: 0,
    document: null,
    parent: null,
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,

    /*
     * args:
     * name      default             desc.
     *
     * width     15                  width
     * height    15                  height
     * document  window.document     explicit document reference
     * target    this.document.body  target element to insert checkbox into
     */
    constructor: function(args){
        if(args === null)
            args = {};

        this.width = args.width || 15;
        this.height = args.height || 15;
        this.document = args.document || window.document;
        this.parent = args.target || this.document.body;
        this.canvas = this.document.createElement("canvas");
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        this.canvas.width = this.width;
        this.canvas.height = this.height;
        this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.ev_click(this), false);
        this.parent.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.draw();
    },

    ev_click: function(self){
        return function(unused){
            self.state = !self.state;
            self.draw();
        }
    },

    draw_rect: function(color, offsetx, offsety){
        this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
        this.ctx.fillRect(offsetx, offsety,
                this.width - offsetx * 2, this.height - offsety * 2);
    },

    draw: function(){
        this.draw_rect("#CCCCCC", 0, 0);
        this.draw_rect("#FFFFFF", 1, 1);
        this.draw_state();
    },

    draw_state: function(){
        if(this.is_checked())
            this.draw_rect("#000000", 2, 2);
    },

    is_checked: function(){
        return this.state == 1;
    }
});

var Checkbox3 = Checkbox.extend({
    ev_click: function(self){
        return function(unused){
            self.state = (self.state + 1) % 3;
            self.draw();
        }
    },

    draw_state: function(){
        if(this.is_checked())
            this.draw_rect("#000000", 2, 2);

        if(this.is_partial())
            this.draw_rect("#000000", 2, (this.height - 2) / 2);
    },

    is_partial: function(){
        return this.state == 2;
    }
});
```

I modified slightly the `Checkbox` used in the last snippet so that it is more generic, making it possible to "extend" it with a checkbox that has 3 states. Here's [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5und7njs/2/). As you can see, it already has more functionality than the built-in checkbox.

Something to consider when you're choosing between JavaScript and CSS.

### Old, poorly-designed code

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txsFA/)

First, set up a canvas

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    checked = 0; // The state of the checkbox
canvas.width = canvas.height = 15; // Set the width and height of the canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' Togglable Option'));
```

Next, devise a way to have the canvas update itself.

```
(function loop(){
  // Draws a border
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,15,15);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 13, 13);
  // Fills in canvas if checked
  if(checked){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(2, 2, 11, 11);
  }
  setTimeout(loop, 1000/10); // Refresh 10 times per second
})();
```

The last part is to make it interactive. Luckily, it's pretty simple:

```
canvas.onclick = function(){
  checked = !checked;
}
```

This is where you might have problems in IE, due to their weird event handling model in JavaScript.

---

I hope this helps someone; it definitely suited my needs.

Comment: Note that the Canvas implementation, as an emulation of checkboxes, allows for more functionality than built-in checkboxes. For example, fancy stuff like "multi-state" checkboxes (i.e. `unchecked (e.g. unchecked -> checked -> "kinda" checked -> unchecked`; the states could represent "explicit false", "explicit true", "use default", for example). I'm considering adding an example to the answer.

Comment: Terrible idea in my opinion.

Comment: @Neil please elaborate

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Neil why *not* reinvent the wheel? NIH isn't always a bad thing, especially when it affords advantages that would otherwise be impossible or stupidly complicated to implement with the existing tech. So it's a question of whether you're willing to deal with the built-in check boxes. And if I am wanting to theme them to blend with the visual language of my website or app, I want full control. So until someone makes a standalone UI library that's lightweight and easy to use, I personally prefer my wheels to be invented here. Someone else might not, but that doesn't invalidate my answer.

Comment: ...or necessarily make the idea terrible, in my opinion (character limit)

Answer (score 5):

## SCSS / SASS Implementation

### A more modern approach

For those using SCSS (or easily converted to SASS), the following will be helpful. Effectively, make an element next to the checkbox, which is the one that you will style. When the checkbox is clicked, the CSS restyles the sister element (to your new, checked style). Code is below:

```css
label.checkbox {
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;

    &:checked + span {
      background: $accent;
    }
  }

  span {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border: 1px solid $accent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.2s $interpol;
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span></span>
    Label text
</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to do it is by styling a `label` and making the `checkbox` invisible.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="first" />
<label for="first">&nbsp;</label>
```

CSS

```css
checkbox {
  display: none;
}

checkbox + label {
  /* Style for checkbox normal */
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

checkbox::checked + label,
label.checked {
  /* Style for checkbox checked */
}
```

The `checkbox`, even though it is hidden, will still be accessible, and its value will be sent when a form is submitted. For old browsers you might have to change the class of the `label` to checked using JavaScript because I don't think old versions of Internet Explorer  understand `::checked` on the `checkbox`.

Comment: The difference between your answer and mine is what exactly?

Comment: @BlakePettersson yours is correct, ::checked is just wrong (I even tried just in case it's also allowed) ;)

Comment: This is a bad answer. (a) `::checked` is wrong—it should be `:checked`. (b) `checkbox` is wrong—it should be `[type=checkbox]`

Comment: You should not hide checkboxe with `display: none` or `visibility: none`, as this breaks accessibility

Answer (score 4):

No JavaScript or jQuery required.

Change your checkbox style simple way.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/mG7QRYw/62a9b364a056b98f7e02705a-checkboxunselected.png");
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
  background: url(https://svgur.com/i/upi.svg);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="option" />
<label for="option"> <span></span> Click me </label>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/05y2bge3/)

Comment: The checkbox isn't showing up, because it relies on external links to image files http://imgh.us/uncheck.png and http://imgh.us/check_2.png which are no longer available online.

Comment: @jkdev I edited it so now the links are online. still waiting for approval

Answer (score 4):

A simple and lightweight template as well:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  content: "\2713";
  background: #fffed5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 15px;
  color: #00904f;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: -3px -3px;
  text-indent: 1px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
  content: "\202A";
  background: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 15px;
  color: #00904f;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: -3px -3px;
  text-indent: 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">checked1<br>
<input type="checkbox">unchecked2<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="id1">
<label for="id1">checked2+label</label><br>
<label for="id2">unchecked2+label+rtl</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id2">
<br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvgccn5b/

Comment: Pseudoelements for `input`s are supported only in Chrome, your code doesn't work the same in every browser.

Answer (score 3):

**Custom checkbox with CSS**  (WebKit browser solution only Chrome, Safari, Mobile browsers)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cardAccptance" name="cardAccptance" value="Yes">
<label for="cardAccptance" class="bold"> Save Card for Future Use</label>
```

CSS:

```
    /* The checkbox-cu */
    
    .checkbox-cu {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox-cu */
    
    .checkbox-cu input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    
    
    /* Create a custom checkbox-cu */
    
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        left: 0;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    
    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    
    .checkbox-cu:hover input~.checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    
    /* When the checkbox-cu is checked, add a blue background */
    
    .checkbox-cu input:checked~.checkmark {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    
    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    
    .checkbox-cu input:checked~.checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }
    
    
    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    
    .checkbox-cu .checkmark::after {
        left: 7px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 6px;
        height: 9px;
        border: solid #28a745;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modern version with a little animation, and simple styling you can customize:

```
.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #7C7A7D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.checkbox:checked {
    border-color: #7C7A7D;
    background-color: #7C7A7D;
}


.checkbox:checked:before {
   position: absolute;
   left: 2px;
   top: -4px;
   display: block;
   content: '\2713';
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 800;
}


.checkbox:hover {
   opacity: 1.0;
   transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/) with a custom stylesheet, you can achieve something like this:

**CSS code**

```
.custom_checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:not(.lever)::before {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd600;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffd600;
  background: transparent;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom_checkbox" />
    <span>Text</span>
</label>
```

**Demo**

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/ge07rz3a/)

Answer (score 3):

This helped me to change style (color) for checkbox

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

We can also use the same for radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CSS/HTML-only version, no jQuery or JavaScript needed at all, Simple and clean HTML and really simple and short CSS.

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/v71kn3pr/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox_01_item" value="red" />
    <label for="myCheckbox_01_item" class="box"></label>
    <label for="myCheckbox_01_item" class="text">I accept the Terms of Use.</label>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#myContainer {
    outline: black dashed 1px;
    width: 200px;
}
#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"] {
    display: none;
}
#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"]:not(:checked) + label.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background: #FFF ;
    margin: 5px 5px;
}
#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"]:checked + label.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background: #F00;
    margin: 5px 5px;
}
#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"] + label + label.text {
    font: normal 12px arial;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 27px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

This can be adapted to be able to have individual radio or checkboxes, grooups of checkboxes and groups of radio buttons as well.

This html/css, will allow you to also capture click on the label, so the checkbox will be checked and unchecked even if you click just on the label.

This type of checkbox/radio button works perfectly with any form, no problem at all. Have been tested using PHP, ASP.NET (.aspx), [JavaServer Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), and [ColdFusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion) too.

Answer (score 2):

No, you still can't style the checkbox itself, but I (finally) figured out how to style an illusion while **keeping the functionality** of clicking a checkbox. It means that you can toggle it even if the cursor isn't perfectly still without risking selecting text or triggering drag-and-drop!

This solution probably also fits radio buttons.

The following works in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 30.0 and Chrome 40.0.2214.91 and is just a basic example. You can still use it in combination with background images and pseudo-elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/o0xo13yL/1/

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; /* Needed for checkbox absolute positioning */
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: .375rem;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

label > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; /* Remove it from the flow */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -.5rem; /* Negative the padding of label to cover the "button" */
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0; /* Make it transparent */
    z-index: 666; /* Place it on top of everything else */
}

label > input[type="checkbox"] + span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
    background-color: #666;
}

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>&nbsp;</span>Label text
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simplest way and you can choose which checkboxes to give this style.

CSS:

```css
.check-box input {
  display: none;
}

.check-box span:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("unchecked.png");
}

.check-box input:checked + span:before {
  background: url("checked.png");
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="check-box">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Check box Text</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since browsers like Edge and Firefox do not support :before :after on checkbox input tags, here is an alternative purely with HTML and CSS. Of course you should edit CSS according to your requirements.

Make the HTML for checkbox like this:

```
<div class='custom-checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <label>
        <span></span>
        Checkbox label
    </label>
</div>
```

Apply this style for the checkbox to change the color label

```
<style>
    .custom-checkbox {
        position: relative;
    }
    .custom-checkbox input{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height:15px;
        width: 50px;    /* Expand the checkbox so that it covers */
        z-index : 1;    /* the label and span, increase z-index to bring it over */
        opacity: 0;     /* the label and set opacity to 0 to hide it. */
    }
    .custom-checkbox input+label {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding-left: 25px;
        color: black;
    }
    .custom-checkbox input+label span {
        position: absolute;  /* a small box to display as checkbox */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .custom-checkbox input:checked+label { /* change label color when checked */
        color: orange;
    }
    .custom-checkbox input:checked+label span{ /* change span box color when checked */
        background-color: orange;
        border: 1px solid orange;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, with theme support. It is a modern approach with CSS transitions. There is absolutely no JavaScript required.

I derived the following code linked in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css#comment89877803_34389136); on a related question.

**Edit:** I added radio buttons, as maxshuty [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570835/1762224).

```js
const selector = '.grid-container > .grid-row > .grid-col[data-theme="retro"]';
const main = () => {
  new CheckboxStyler().run(selector);
  new RadioStyler().run(selector);
};

/*
 * This is only used to add the wrapper class and checkmark span to an existing DOM,
 * to make this CSS work.
 */
class AbstractInputStyler {
  constructor(options) {
    this.opts = options;
  }
  run(parentSelector) {
    let wrapperClass = this.opts.wrapperClass;
    let parent = document.querySelector(parentSelector) || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    let labels = parent.querySelectorAll('label');
    if (labels.length) labels.forEach(label => {
      if (label.querySelector(`input[type="${this.opts._inputType}"]`)) {
        if (!label.classList.contains(wrapperClass)) {
          label.classList.add(wrapperClass);
          label.appendChild(this.__createDefaultNode());
        }
      }
    });
    return this;
  }
  /* @protected */
  __createDefaultNode() {
    let checkmark = document.createElement('span');
    checkmark.className = this.opts._activeClass;
    return checkmark;
  }
}

class CheckboxStyler extends AbstractInputStyler {
  constructor(options) {
    super(Object.assign({
      _inputType: 'checkbox',
      _activeClass: 'checkmark'
    }, CheckboxStyler.defaultOptions, options));
  }
}
CheckboxStyler.defaultOptions = {
  wrapperClass: 'checkbox-wrapper'
};

class RadioStyler extends AbstractInputStyler {
  constructor(options) {
    super(Object.assign({
      _inputType: 'radio',
      _activeClass: 'pip'
    }, RadioStyler.defaultOptions, options));
  }
}
RadioStyler.defaultOptions = {
  wrapperClass: 'radio-wrapper'
};

main();
```

```css
/* Theming */

:root {
  --background-color: #FFF;
  --font-color: #000;
  --checkbox-default-background: #EEE;
  --checkbox-hover-background: #CCC;
  --checkbox-disabled-background: #AAA;
  --checkbox-selected-background: #1A74BA;
  --checkbox-selected-disabled-background: #6694B7;
  --checkbox-checkmark-color: #FFF;
  --checkbox-checkmark-disabled-color: #DDD;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --background-color: #111;
  --font-color: #EEE;
  --checkbox-default-background: #222;
  --checkbox-hover-background: #444;
  --checkbox-disabled-background: #555;
  --checkbox-selected-background: #2196F3;
  --checkbox-selected-disabled-background: #125487;
  --checkbox-checkmark-color: #EEE;
  --checkbox-checkmark-disabled-color: #999;
}

[data-theme="retro"] {
  --background-color: #FFA;
  --font-color: #000;
  --checkbox-default-background: #EEE;
  --checkbox-hover-background: #FFF;
  --checkbox-disabled-background: #BBB;
  --checkbox-selected-background: #EEE;
  --checkbox-selected-disabled-background: #BBB;
  --checkbox-checkmark-color: #F44;
  --checkbox-checkmark-disabled-color: #D00;
}


/* General styles */

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /*background: var(--background-color); -- For demo, moved to column. */
  /*color:      var(--font-color);       -- For demo, moved to column. */
  background: #777;
  width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  height: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  padding: 0.25em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.33em !important;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.15em !important;
  margin-top: 1em;
}


/* Grid style - using flex */

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
}

.grid-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
  /* If not demo, remove and uncomment the body color rules */
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
}

.grid-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* The checkbox wrapper */

.checkbox-wrapper,
.radio-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox and radio buttons */

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkbox-wrapper .checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background-color: var(--checkbox-default-background);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.radio-wrapper .pip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--checkbox-default-background);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}


/* Disabled style */

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:disabled~.checkmark,
.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"]:disabled~.pip {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: var(--checkbox-disabled-background);
  color: var(--checkbox-checkmark-disabled-color);
}

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:disabled~.checkmark:after,
.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"]:disabled~.pip:after {
  color: var(--checkbox-checkmark-disabled-color);
}

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked~.checkmark,
.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"]:disabled:checked~.pip {
  background-color: var(--checkbox-selected-disabled-background);
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.checkbox-wrapper:hover input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):not(:checked)~.checkmark,
.radio-wrapper:hover input[type="radio"]:not(:disabled):not(:checked)~.pip {
  background-color: var(--checkbox-hover-background);
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checkmark,
.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked~.pip {
  background-color: var(--checkbox-selected-background);
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkbox-wrapper .checkmark:after {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\2713";
  color: var(--checkbox-checkmark-color);
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.radio-wrapper .pip:after {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\2022";
  color: var(--checkbox-checkmark-color);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: -0.2em;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.radio-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked~.pip:after {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-cell">
        <h1>Pure CSS</h1>
        <h2>Checkbox</h2>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">One
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Two
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Three
          <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Four
          <input type="checkbox" disabled>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <h2>Radio</h2>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">One
          <input type="radio" name="group-x">
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Two
          <input type="radio" name="group-x">
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Three
          <input type="radio" name="group-x" checked disabled>
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Four
          <input type="radio" name="group-x" disabled>
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-col" data-theme="dark">
      <div class="grid-cell">
        <h1>Pure CSS</h1>
        <h2>Checkbox</h2>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">One
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Two
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Three
          <input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-wrapper">Four
          <input type="checkbox" disabled>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <h2>Radio</h2>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">One
          <input type="radio" name="group-y">
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Two
          <input type="radio" name="group-y">
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Three
          <input type="radio" name="group-y" checked disabled>
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-wrapper">Four
          <input type="radio" name="group-y" disabled>
          <span class="pip"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-col" data-theme="retro">
      <div class="grid-cell">
        <h1>JS + CSS</h1>
        <h2>Checkbox</h2>
        <label>One   <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></label>
        <label>Two   <input type="checkbox"></label>
        <label>Three <input type="checkbox" checked disabled></label>
        <label>Four  <input type="checkbox" disabled></label>
        <h2>Radio</h2>
        <label>One   <input type="radio" name="group-z" checked="checked"></label>
        <label>Two   <input type="radio" name="group-z"></label>
        <label>Three <input type="radio" name="group-z" checked disabled></label>
        <label>Four  <input type="radio" name="group-z" disabled></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide the input and add a before to the next element that create a checkbox equivalent

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;    
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  content:'';
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #0079bf;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color:red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a white background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid green;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to change all of a checkbox's colors by using only CSS:

- As mentioned, the recent `accent-color` CSS property is useful for changing a checkbox color when it's *checked*.
- However, what I haven't seen anyone else mention is that when the checkbox is *unchecked* you can change the background colors and/or borders if you make use of CSS's `filter` property.

For simple changes, you can use `brightness` to turn the white background color darker into grays or black, and using `hue-rotate` you can give colors to the borders (at least in Firefox). However, if you want to fully change the background to any colors, you can also do that with `filters`, but you'll have to do some trickery where you combine multiple filters based on the approach in this question: [How to transform black into any given color using only CSS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/43960991#43960991)

Fortunately, this complex approach seems to works in all browsers and there are generators you can use to calculate the `filters` needed for whichever colors you want: https://codepen.io/jumarjuaton/full/mdJYWYq
(this link specifically transforms from white, unlike the question linked above)

See examples below:

```css
/* Disable 'filters' while checked since they impact 'accent-color'. */
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    filter: none;
}
input[type='radio']:checked {
    filter: none;
}

/**
 * We use 'accent-color' for colors in the checked stated and we use
 * 'filter' to change the background colors in the unchecked state.
 */
.red-bg-input {
  accent-color: red;
  filter: invert(85%) sepia(83%) saturate(6726%) hue-rotate(360deg) brightness(111%) contrast(111%);
}

.green-bg-input {
  accent-color: green;
  filter: invert(49%) sepia(65%) saturate(7149%) hue-rotate(92deg) brightness(89%) contrast(103%);
}

.blue-bg-input {
  accent-color: blue;
  filter: invert(30%) sepia(99%) saturate(6101%) hue-rotate(202deg) brightness(52%) contrast(136%);
}

.teal-bg-input {
  accent-color: teal;
  filter: invert(58%) sepia(77%) saturate(3139%) hue-rotate(157deg) brightness(89%) contrast(101%)
}

.dark-input {
  accent-color: black;
  filter: brightness(0%) saturate(100) hue-rotate(25deg);
}

.gray-input {
  accent-color: purple;
  filter: brightness(60%) saturate(100) hue-rotate(25deg);
}

.orange-bg-input {
  accent-color: orange;
  filter: invert(63%) sepia(28%) saturate(7249%) hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(103%) contrast(105%);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
<input type="radio" />
<input type="radio" checked />
Defaults

<br>
<input class="red-bg-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="red-bg-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="red-bg-input" type="radio" />
<input class="red-bg-input" type="radio" checked/>
Red

<br>
<input class="green-bg-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="green-bg-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="green-bg-input" type="radio" />
<input class="green-bg-input" type="radio" checked/>
Green

<br>
<input class="blue-bg-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="blue-bg-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="blue-bg-input" type="radio" />
<input class="blue-bg-input" type="radio" checked/>
Blue

<br>
<input class="teal-bg-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="teal-bg-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="teal-bg-input" type="radio" />
<input class="teal-bg-input" type="radio" checked/>
Teal

<br>
<input class="orange-bg-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="orange-bg-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="orange-bg-input" type="radio" />
<input class="orange-bg-input" type="radio" checked/>
Orange

<br>
<input class="dark-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="dark-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="dark-input" type="radio" />
<input class="dark-input" type="radio" checked/>
Black/dark

<br>
<input class="gray-input" type="checkbox" />
<input class="gray-input" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input class="gray-input" type="radio" />
<input class="gray-input" type="radio" checked/>
Purple + Gray background
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.gf-checkbox-input{
    accent-color: #5bbce2;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.gf-checkbox-label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<label className="gf-checkbox-label">
   <input type = 'checkbox' className="gf-checkbox-input" />
   Checkbox  
</label>
```

Comment: Please explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.css-label{
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/dark-check-green.png);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can change the colour of the checkbox in grayscale by using CSS only.

The following converts the checkboxes from black to gray (which was about what I wanted):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: this makes the border light too. also, you can't really see the check if you check it.

Answer (score 0):

[`CodepenLink`](https://codepen.io/aruna-thakur/pen/LYrgBpw)[image][image: CSS properties is accent-color:red;]

**- Just add the CSS properties. No need to add any Javascript.**

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way to change html checkbox color is**

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
accent-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/). It is customized checkboxes and radio buttons for jQuery & Zepto, and maybe it will help you.

Make sure jQuery v1.7+ is loaded before the icheck.js

1. Choose a color scheme, there are 10 different styles available:

   - Black — minimal.css
   - Red — red.css
   - Green — green.css
   - Blue — blue.css
   - Aero — aero.css
   - Grey — grey.css
   - Orange — orange.css
   - Yellow — yellow.css
   - Pink — pink.css
   - Purple — purple.css
2. Copy /skins/minimal/ folder and icheck.js file to your site.
3. Insert before  in your HTML (replace your-path and color-scheme):

   ```
   <link href="your-path/minimal/color-scheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="your-path/icheck.js"></script>
   ```

   Example for a Red color scheme:

   ```
   <link href="your-path/minimal/red.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="your-path/icheck.js"></script>
   ```
4. Add some checkboxes and radio buttons to your HTML:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <input type="radio" name="iCheck">
   <input type="radio" name="iCheck" checked>
   ```
5. Add JavaScript to your HTML to launch iCheck plugin:

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input').iCheck({
           checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
           radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
           increaseArea: '20%' // Optional
         });
      });
   </script>
   ```
6. For different from black color schemes use this code (example for Red):

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input').iCheck({
           checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
           radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red',
           increaseArea: '20%' // Optional
         });
      });
   </script>
   ```
7. Done

Answer (score -3):

**Warning**: the following was true at the time of writing, but in the meantime things have progressed.

AFAIK modern browsers display checkboxes using the native OS control, so there's no way to style them.

Comment: It may have been true in '10, but not now, you should delete this answer.

Comment: Its still true - all modern browsers display checkboxes using native OS control.  Its just that there are some cool new techniques to work around this limitation.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the "there's no way to style them" part ^^

Answer (score -3):

This will make the dotted border, aswell as the background your seeking, also, if you want to set a specific background color for when checked, simply set it where apropriate in below example for your issue :)
This solution also sets in a custom checkmark icon, etc.

for an html element like:
`<input type="checkbox" />`

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  background-color: rgb(60,69,77,0.9);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
  content: '\2713';
  color:white;
}
input[type='checkbox']{
  background:#ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  appearance:none;
  border-radius:10%;
  border: 1px dotted rgb(60,69,77,0.9);
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -14):

Quick fix to add icon in front of text:

```
< asp:CheckBox... Text="< img src='/link/to/img.png' />My Text" />
```

Comment: asp:CheckBox? What is that in CSS / HTML?

Comment: and CSS HTML it is:  <i dont='understand' the='question'/>