# How to align checkbox and label tag?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

I have this code:

```
<div id="form-footer">
    <ul>
       <li>
           <label for="test">Label text</label> 
           <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="test" />
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I align the label and the checkbox? At the moment I see the checkbox align on top with respect to the label, I would like to see it in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

if everything is one-line you could use the line-height property:

```
#form-footer li { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; /** same as height */ }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
​input[type=checkbox] { vertical-align: middle; }​
```

Or any of the `vertical-align` properties