# how to hide password character in text field

Tags: java, jsp

I know how to let user input their password with input type="password" field in JSP. 
But I get their input password using servlet, it would show all characters. How do you hide these characters in regular HTML or JSP?

For instance, if I have

## password: MKS09js5

how do I hide or make the password ********? (This is not for search or input)

Comment: Are you asking how to conceal the password across the network in case someone's packet-sniffing? Or are you saying your servlet receives the password in plaintext instead of `********`, and you would like to make it `*********`to make it difficult for the servlet?

Comment: My servlet stores the password in plaintext. I have provided a JSP to display user info like username and password etc. In that JSP, the password for this user is currently displayed in plaintext. How can I display it with *****?

Comment: Couldn't you just manually render it as `******`? Like literally hardcode it. I mean, presumably they're supposed to know their password. Unless you want the exact number of `*`'s?

Comment: The answer below didn't really answer my question since this is used to ask for user input.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually type ******"? This ****** is the password from my mysql database. I just want to print this to JSP with encryption.

Comment: That is what I am confused about. If all the user is going to see is ****** then why not just hardcode that value in your JSP so that it will be rendered as a sequence of *'s?

Comment: Agree with MxyL. What will the purpose of this password field be. Do you want the user to be able to see their password or not? I don't get it. If you wanted the user to just know this is a password field then like @MxyL says hard code the ****.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this can help you.

```
<form:password path="password_field_name" value="my_password"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the input type "password" property as shown in w3schools website.

```
<form>
 Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
 </form>
```

[W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: I know how to do with input type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419780/javascript-show-hide-password   Maybe this is what you want?