# Displaying password only when the button is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

How to display a Button, when it is clicked, It display a PHP code which then displays content from Database, specifically I have created an SQL query in PHP where I am displaying user's details from my table, like Email, Username, Password. I want to make Password hidden, so when user click on "display" button, only then the password will be shown.
Below is my php code to display all data from database:

```
{
<?php
include_once('confi.php');
//*********retrieving data from Database**********
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name, email, username, password  FROM demo");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
printf ("</br> ID: %s </br> Name: %s  </br> Email: %s </br> Username: %s </br> Password: %s </br>",  $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);
} 
?>
}
```

I want to make password visible only when a button or anything like "show password" button is clicked. How can I make that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224651/show-hide-password-onclick-of-button-using-javascript-only

Comment: Just a quick note that it is a very bad idea to store plain text passwords in a database. If you are learning about passwords and databases, it's time to learn about salting and hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the input field type is password and show the password when user click the checkbox . change the field type to text using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(':checkbox').change(function(){
  
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
        
        $(this).prev('input').attr('type','text');
        
        }
    else
      {
          $(this).prev('input').attr('type','password');
        }
    
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="test1" value="a" />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />Show password
```

Comment: That code works, but I want to hide the password that is fetched directly from my database. I don't want user to enter any password. I just want his password to be hidden when displayed from database, to the web page.
As for example, if you look into my code, the sql query displays all data including password, I don't want that password to be visible. I want it to be visible only when user clicks "show"

Comment: simple set the input field disabled

Comment: you just post your html we will work through it @VishalLimbachiya

Answer (score 2):

```
Using jquery we can do this . Here's a link (http://jsfiddle.net/herdiansc/dnznh/8/)
```