# Password encryption using HTMl and Java with toggle button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a website or say HTML page where the password can have special characters. Below username and password there should be a toggle button on click of which it will show the encrypted password and clicking again it will show decrypted or alphanumeric password.

I want to do it using HTML and JavaScript or HTML and Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Show/Hide toggle button for password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390966/javascript-show-hide-toggle-button-for-password-field)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Manipulating the element by changing its type from password to text is the easiest way. You could try something like `document.getElementById("password").type = "text"`