# Jquery show/hide password

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Below Jquery is working fine but How could I shorten this Jquery? I have to show and hide the password for password and confirmed password? https://jsfiddle.net/c5cvLo54/1/

```
$(".password-showhide .show-password").click(function() {
    $("#password").attr("type", "text");
    $(".password-showhide .show-password").hide();
    $(".password-showhide .hide-password").show();
});
$(".password-showhide .hide-password").click(function() {
    $("#password").attr("type", "password");
    $(".password-showhide .hide-password").hide();
    $(".password-showhide .show-password").show();
});

$(".confirm-password-showhide .show-password").click(function() {
    $("#confirmPassword").attr("type", "text");
    $(".confirm-password-showhide .show-password").hide();
    $(".confirm-password-showhide .hide-password").show();
});
$(".confirm-password-showhide .hide-password").click(function() {
    $("#confirmPassword").attr("type", "password");
    $(".confirm-password-showhide .hide-password").hide();
    $(".confirm-password-showhide .show-password").show();
});
```

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c5cvLo54/

Comment: Below links will be helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419780/javascript-show-hide-password
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Show-Hide-Password-Field-Text-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/

Comment: Full code is in https://jsfiddle.net/c5cvLo54/1/

Comment: @SameerAli Take a look at the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one-of-the ways, how you can shorten your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".show-password, .hide-password").on('click', function() {
    var passwordId = $(this).parents('li:first').find('input').attr('id');
    if ($(this).hasClass('show-password')) {
      $("#" + passwordId).attr("type", "text");
      $(this).parent().find(".show-password").hide();
      $(this).parent().find(".hide-password").show();
    } else {
      $("#" + passwordId).attr("type", "password");
      $(this).parent().find(".hide-password").hide();
      $(this).parent().find(".show-password").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.hide-password {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <span class="password-showhide">
<span class="show-password">Show</span>
    <span class="hide-password">hide</span>
    </span>
    <li>
      <li>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="confirmPassword" />
        <span class="confirm-password-showhide">
<span class="show-password">Show</span>
        <span class="hide-password">hide</span>
        </span>
        <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks..code looks better now....is there any further scope to shortened?

Comment: Well, with the current HTML structure, I don't think this can be simplified more.

Comment: Thanks Milan, I appreciate your quick turn around :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can up-vote and accept this answer. Happy Coding!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use only one button to control.

**JS:**

```
$('.showOrHide').click(function(e){
    var target = e.currentTarget
    $(target).hasClass('show')?hidePassword($(target)):showPassword($(target))
})
function hidePassword(e){
    e.removeClass('show').addClass('hide')
    e.prev('input').attr('type','password')
}
function showPassword(e){
    e.removeClass('hide').addClass('show')
    e.prev('input').attr('type','text')
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value="123456">
<button class="showOrHide show">click</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.show{
    /* css you want */
    color: blue
}
.hide{
    /* css you want */
    color: red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created this basically by taking reference from Google's show password toggle on their login forms.

This basically checks whether a check box is checked or not.

If checked then it changes the input type of password to text and vice versa.

```js
<!-- Toggle password visibility -->

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#show-password").change(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked") ?  $("#upassword").prop("type", "text") : $("#upassword").prop("type", "password");    
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" name="password" id="upassword" />
<input type="checkbox" id="show-password">
  <label for="show-password">Show Password
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest i think you can get

```
$(".confirm-password-showhide .trigger-password, .password-showhide .trigger-password").click(function() {
  var c = $(this).parent().attr("class").replace("-showhide", "");
  var obj = $("#" + (c.indexOf("confirm") > -1 ? "confirmPassword" : "password"));
  obj.attr("type", obj.attr("type") == "text" ? "password" : "text");
  $(this).text($(this).text() == "hide" ? "show" : "hide");
});
```

I've also removed the "hide" span from each of the passwords.

```js
$(".confirm-password-showhide .trigger-password, .password-showhide .trigger-password").click(function() {
  var c = $(this).parent().attr("class").replace("-showhide", "");
  var obj = $("#" + (c.indexOf("confirm") > -1 ? "confirmPassword" : "password"));
  obj.attr("type", obj.attr("type") == "text" ? "password" : "text");
  $(this).text($(this).text() == "hide" ? "show" : "hide");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <span class="password-showhide"><span class="trigger-password">Show</span></span>
  </li>
  <li><input type="password" name="password" id="confirmPassword"> <span class="confirm-password-showhide"><span class="trigger-password">Show</span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But we cannot remove the spans as the text has to be editable and come from dialog.

Answer (score 0):

show/Hide password function

```
function togglePassword($element){
    var newtype=$element.prop('type')=='password'?'text':'password';
    $element.prop('type',newtype);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#showUserNewPass').change(function(){
          togglePassword($('#userNewPass'));
          togglePassword($('#confirmNewPassword'));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>This Password Hide & Show</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        #password
        {
            width: 50%;

        }
        #open
        {
            color: gray;
        }
        #closed
        {
            display: none;
            color: steelblue;
        }
        i
        {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -30px;
            margin-left: 280px;
        }
    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#open").click(function(){
                 $("#open").hide();
                 $("#closed").show();
                 $("#password").attr("type","text");
             });

             $("#closed").click(function(){
                 $("#closed").hide();
                 $("#open").show();
                 $("#password").attr("type","password");
             });

         });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Password Hide & Show</h4>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="pwd">
    <i id="open" class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
    <i id="closed" class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-2x"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <h2>Show or Hide Password</h2>
            <p class="instructions">Hover on the eye to show/hide the password</p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script>
        $("#show_password").hover(
          function functionName() {
            //Change the attribute to text
            $("#password").attr("type", "text");
            $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-eye-open").addClass("glyphicon-eye-close");
          },
          function () {
            //Change the attribute back to password
            $("#password").attr("type", "password");
            $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-eye-close").addClass("glyphicon-eye-open");
          }
        );
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can add the eye icon inside the password textbox and toggle the visibility of the password using CSS and JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle-password").click(function () {
        var passwordInput = $($(this).siblings(".password-input"));
        var icon = $(this);
        if (passwordInput.attr("type") == "password") {
            passwordInput.attr("type", "text");
            icon.removeClass("fa-eye").addClass("fa-eye-slash");
        } else {
            passwordInput.attr("type", "password");
            icon.removeClass("fa-eye-slash").addClass("fa-eye");
        }
    });
})
```

```css
.password-input-container {
    position: relative;
}

.password-input {
    padding-right: 32px;
}

.toggle-password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="mt-2" for="txtPasswordLogin">Password</label>
    <div class="password-input-container">
        <input type="password" class="form-control password-input" id="txtPasswordLogin" placeholder="Enter Password">
        <i class="toggle-password fa fa-eye"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
        
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#btn').click(function(){

                var paswd= $('#password');
                if(paswd.attr("type")== "password"){

                    paswd.attr("type","text");

                    $('#btn').attr("value","hide");
                    
                }
                else{
                        paswd.attr("type","password");

                        $('#btn').attr("value","show");
                }
            })
        });
    
       
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't post answers of just code. Please explain what your code does in detail. Thanks.