# How to show and hide password when click on eye icon using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement to show and hide user password when click on eye icon so I had written script for that,when I click on eye icon only class is changing but password  is not visible and again click on slash-eye icon it should hidden  both these method not working how to solve this issue?

```
<input type="password" name="player_password" id="pass_log_id" />

<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>

<script>
$("body").on('click','.toggle-password',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");

    var input = $("#pass_log_id").attr("type");

    if (input.attr("type") === "password") {
        input.attr("type", "text");
    } else {
        input.attr("type", "password");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561636/jquery-show-hide-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery show/hide password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561636/jquery-show-hide-password)

Comment: A working code example here https://codepen.io/Sohail05/pen/yOpeBm

Comment: @Manasi plz tell me what is wrong in my code

Comment: @SudhirOjha post link which you have sent is looking complex so please tell me what is wrong in my code so i can correct that

Comment: @MSp you are doing ** ".attr("type");"  2 times. ** 1) var input = $("#pass_log_id").attr("type"); and 2) if (input.attr("type") === "password")

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `input` is actually string. Check console, you should see that string does not have method `attr()` because you assign `$().attr()` to `input`

```js
$("body").on('click', '.toggle-password', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $("#pass_log_id");
  if (input.attr("type") === "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password">Show/Hide</span>
<input type="password" id="pass_log_id"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to remove var `.attr("type");` from your `var input = $("#pass_log_id").attr("type");`. 
You also can do it more elegant with `ternary operator` to toggle between `type text` and `password`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-password', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
    
    var input = $("#pass_log_id");
    input.attr('type') === 'password' ? input.attr('type','text') : input.attr('type','password')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
 
<body>
<input id="pass_log_id" type="password" name="pass" value="MySecretPass">
<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>

</body>
```

Comment: If you're going for ternary, then go all the way:

`input.attr('type', input.attr('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password')`

Answer (score 5):

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show <input type="password" id="myInput" value="Password">


<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
      x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const togglePasswordEye = '<i class="fa fa-eye toggle-password-eye"></i>';
const togglePasswordEyeSlash = '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash toggle-password-eye"></i>';

$(togglePasswordEyeSlash).insertAfter('input[type=password]');
$('input[type=password]').addClass('hidden-pass-input')

$('body').on('click', '.toggle-password-eye', function (e) {
    let password = $(this).prev('.hidden-pass-input');

    if (password.attr('type') === 'password') {
        password.attr('type', 'text');
        $(this).addClass('fa-eye').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    } else {
        password.attr('type', 'password');
        $(this).addClass('fa-eye-slash').removeClass('fa-eye');
    }
})
```

```css
.toggle-password-eye {
    float: right;
    top: -25px;
    right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why has this not been accepted as the correct answer? It helped me alot.

Comment: i've tried but not working

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

> var input = $("#pass_log_id").attr("type");

with

> > var input = $("#pass_log_id");

you need the element not the attribute,

Answer (score 1):

HTML code

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" class="masked" name="password" 
/>
<button type="button" onclick="showHide()" id="eye">
   <img src="eye.png" alt="eye"/>
 </button>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#eye").click(function () {
        if ($("#password").attr("type") === "password") {
            $("#password").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $("#password").attr("type", "password");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple script with handle password toggle
**Html and javascript code**

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
    <img src="eye-close.png" onclick="handle()" id="eyeicon">
</div>

<script>

    function handle() {

        var pass = document.getElementById('pass')
        var eyeicon = document.getElementById('eyeicon')

        if (pass.type == "password") {
            pass.type = "text"
            eyeicon.src = "eye-open.png";
        } else {
            pass.type = "password"
            eyeicon.src = "eye-close.png";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function click() {
     // toggle the type attribute
    const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");
    const passwordV = document.querySelector("#password_field");
    const type = passwordV.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
    togglePassword.className === 'fa fa-eye-slash viewpass mr-4 text-muted' ? document.getElementById("togglePassword").className = 'fa fa-eye viewpass mr-4 text-muted' : document.getElementById("togglePassword").className = 'fa fa-eye-slash viewpass mr-4 text-muted';
    passwordV.setAttribute("type", type);

}


<input type="password" id="password_field"/>

<span className="fa fa-eye-slash viewpass mr-4 text-muted" onClick={click} id="togglePassword"></span>
```

In add CSS

```
  .viewpass{
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: large;
  z-index: 2;
}
```