# I want to customize my password field in django admin panel to implement hide/unhide functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to customize my password field in django admin panel to implement hide/unhide functionality.

#app/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class CustomInput(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want to add a "eye" sign in password field and implement hide/unhide functionality inside my admin panel.

[Please refer image for admin panel reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPSLH.png)

Comment: Normally passwords are never stored in an accessible format in the database: the password is hashed, so the original password can never be retrieved. Not hashing credentials is often seen as a severe security vulnerability.

Comment: these answers can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857014/how-to-add-password-toggle-functionality-on-a-form-extended-from-djangos-built