# Javascript toggle between show and hide a password

Tags: javascript, passwords, hide, show

I have been working on a project that requires me to toggle between showing and hiding the password in a password field.

The JS code I came up with is:

```html
<script>
  function text(item) {
    if (document.getElementById('password').type = "password") {
      document.getElementById('password').type = "text";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('password').type = "password";
    }

  }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="logon-show-password" name="showpassword" class="tickable" onclick="text(this)">

<input type="password" id="password" />
```

For some reason, it works just fine when toggling between password -> text, but fails to do the opposite.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question may be duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419780/javascript-show-hide-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `=` in the if condition

```
if(document.getElementById('password').type="password"){
                                          ^^^^
```

Should be

```
if(document.getElementById('password').type=="password"){
```

Otherwise it will assign the type password to the field and it will return true always

```js
function text(item) {
  if (document.getElementById('password').type == "password") {
    document.getElementById('password').type = "text";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('password').type = "password";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="logon-show-password" name="showpassword" class="tickable" onclick="text(this)">
<input id="password" type="password" />
```