# Aligning checkbox text with checkbox with CSS

Tags: html, css, class, checkbox, fieldset

I have a fieldset in which I have some input fields and a checkbox. I have the problem that I would like to have a legend directly beside the checkbox. I made it visible on this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uUtmU/

I worked around and tried using `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom`, without any success.

If there is someone who could help me out, I really would appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey now give to **input** `vertical-align: top;` as like this

```
#split input[type="checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just absolute the positioning on the terms text and set a margin-top to push it down a little, I found by adding

```
.tandc {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Hope it helps