# Facing IE8 and Firefox Alignment issue of the text of a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-8, text-alignment

I am using the checkbox in the following manner.
The screen shot in **Firefox**
[image]

And the sceen shot in **IE8** is here

[image]

Here is the code

```
<div>
   <div>Testing :</div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" value="1"/> One</div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" value="2"/> Two</div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" value="3"/> Three</div>
</div>
```

How to align the text at the center vertical in both the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your CSS -

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7XgW/)

Inline CSS trick works on WIN XP. Try -

```
<div><input type="checkbox" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> One</div>
```

Comment: Its not working. Even in the demo it doesn't look like it is center vertical

Comment: I am on a windows xp and checking it on IE8 and firefox and it is not at the middle :(

Comment: I tried that also... still it is the same as in the screen shot even in the demo

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Here is your solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try using with different css :

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

write your own css for checkbox in this file for ie 8