# A issue with align the checkbox and text

Tags: css, less

I'm having some problems with my page, I'm using less css and one of atributes css is the line-height is not working so very well. On all browser appears the same mode but on the IE it appears different.

This is the problem:
[image]

If you take a look. will see that the IE shows the text more higher than the checkbox on IE

I'm using a variable to define the line-height, so I'm wish know if exists some hack or trick to use two values to the same variable (i.e line-height = 20 - if any browser,  line-height = 25 - if IE browser, or some way to resolve this issue.

I just want align the checkbox and the text.

Comment: conditional code works. post some code.

Comment: I suggest taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`<!--[if IE]>
<style>
</style>
<![endif]-->`