# How to wrap long radiobutton label in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1, radiobuttonlist

[image: Long Label in a RadioButton]

My above radion button wraps the label, but it is not aligned properly. It should align right below the first text on the top. Is there a config I have to set inorder for the labels to wrap correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure there is no config to do this. Only reasonable way is by fiddling with CSS - [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

+In current version (4.2.1.), there is a bug, which wraps whole label text under the radio ([see here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265217)).

Comment: Thanks Michal... I sort of used your approach using CSS... Not an ideal solution but it works... Hopefully they come up with some config with their new update

Answer (score 0):

By looking at what ExtJS 6 implemented. You can use this CSS overwrite on ExtJS 4.2.1:

```
.x-form-cb-label-after {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 17px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
.x-form-cb {
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And accomplish this:
[image]