# Incorrect boxLabel wrap in a checkboxgroup (ExtJs4.2)

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I'm having a problem with the box labels of the checkboxes being wrapped under the checkbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/6pYWh/

```
        {
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Item 1',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '1'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 2 with large box label does not wrap properly',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '2',
                checked: true
            }]
        }
```

I need the wrap to be inline-block with both blocks in the same line, so i have to force the width of the second block to a certain size in order to accomplish that:

http://jsfiddle.net/595Md/

The problem is that i'm not seeing a way to accomplish this dynamicaly, so if you resize the west panel, the box label width will have to be recalculated and updated in order to use all the space now available and still maintain the wrap at the same level of the checkbox.

Any toughts?

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar (but different) question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35432681/1385429. I posted the answer here to. It was a duplicate answer and so a moderator deleted it. And rightfully so. Unfortunately he choose to delete the answer to this question. Deleting it at the other question would have been more appropriate. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following css selector.

```
.hello-world {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Then, try this.

```
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function () {

var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        padding: 5
    },
    defaults: {
        split: true
    },
    items: [{
        region: 'west',
        collapsible: true,
        header: false,
        split: true,
        width: 200,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,
            id: 'cb-group',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Item 1',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '1'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 2 with large box label does not wrap properly',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '2',
                checked: true
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 3',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '3'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 4',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '4'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 5',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '5'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Item 6',
                name: 'rb',
                inputValue: '6'
            }],
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function() {
                    for (var i = 1; i < Ext.getCmp('cb-group').items.length; i++) {
                        if (Ext.getCmp('cb-group').items.items[i].boxLabel.length > 24 ) {
                            Ext.getCmp('cb-group').items.items[i].boxLabelCls = "hello-world";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }, {
        region: 'center',
        html: 'center',
        title: 'Center'
    }, {
        region: 'south',
        title: 'South',
        height: 100,
        split: true,
        collapsible: true,
        html: 'south'
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: Like i said in the question, it has to be dynamic, i can't hardcode a width value, or i would have used the solution in the second fiddler i posted